# Change the branch name on github that references HEAD

Tags: github

In my remote bare repository the HEAD is pointing to "refs/heads/master" and I want it to point to "refs/heads/other".

I am not able to go to remote repository directory and run `git symbolic-ref`. Is there any git command to achieve it? Or any other way?

If there is no way, does Github allow one to change the HEAD?

Answer (score 6):

To change it in github, go to the admin section.
You can select the default branch from a dropdown there.

Comment: Hmmmm... the existence of that drop-down is a strong indicator that there's no way to do it purely using Git commands.

Answer (score 4):

(There has been posted another question asking basically the same: [How do I change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides “master”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master/2962737), and there was more discussion there, with [a reference to the Github group](http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/eb3046a7b4c8bec7/b64ee724a0db5471). So I'd just like to point anyone to that discussion as well.)

As we know,  there is no universal answer.

But there are a specific answers for various git "farms" (where multiple users can manage git repos through a restricted interface: via http and ssh): http://Github.com, http://Gitorious.org, http://repo.or.cz, [Girar](http://en.altlinux.org/Git.alt) (http://git.altlinux.org).

These specific answers might be useful for those reading this page and thinking about these specific services.

- Now they have a drop-down menu for selecting the HEAD branch at **http://repo.or.cz** (example: http://repo.or.cz/editproj.cgi?name=for-me-and-for-all_imz.git);
- and at **http://gitorious.org**, too (look somewhere in the settings);
- and at **http://GitHub.com**: admin > Default Branch > (choose something) (thanks to @srcspider's answer);
- and in **[Girar](http://en.altlinux.org/Git.alt)** (running on http://git.altlinux.org to build packages for ALT's distro), one can the ssh interface for this:

```
$ ssh git.alt help | fgrep branch
default-branch  []
$
```

for example `ssh git.alt default-branch packages/autosshd.git sisyphus` to change the HEAD in the remote repo `autosshd.git` to point to the `sisyphus` branch.

Comment: This should have been a comment, because it's not an answer.

Comment: It's a perfect answer. _Is there any git command to \[change a symbolic ref on a remote repository\]? Or any other way?_ There is no git command, but here are a few examples of how you do it on various git hosting services.