# Change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

How do I set a Git remote's HEAD reference to point to something besides "master"?

My project has a policy not to use a "master" branch (all branches are to have meaningful names). Furthermore, the canonical master repository is only accessible via ssh://, with no shell access (like GitHub or Unfuddle).

My problem is that the remote repository still has a HEAD reference to refs/heads/master, but I need it to point to a different branch.  This is causing two problems:

1. When cloning the repo, there this,

   > warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.

   That's confusing and inconvenient.
2. The web-based code browser depends on HEAD as a basis for browsing the tree. I need HEAD to point to a valid branch, then.

Comment: Just added one possibility for the record, but not suitable for your case.

Comment: "no-common-ancestor" trick: interesting. You could post it as a detailed answer and select it as the official one if you find it working.

Comment: FWIW, since you mentioned GitHub in the question -- if you want to change the HEAD ref on GitHub, just go to the repository's "Admin" screen, and change the "Default Branch" dropdown to whatever branch you want HEAD to point to.

Comment: See also https://help.github.com/articles/error-remote-head-refers-to-nonexistent-ref-unable-to-checkout

Comment: possible duplicate of [create a git symbolic ref in remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847609/create-a-git-symbolic-ref-in-remote-repository)

Comment: A better asked question with a very good accepted answer is [Git: Correct way to change Active Branch in a bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3301956/260122), if you are on a repo where you have command-line access. For a repo on a hosting service, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962737/260122 below.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There was almost the [same question on GitHub](http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/eb3046a7b4c8bec7/b64ee724a0db5471) a year ago.

The idea was to rename the master branch:

```
git branch -m master development
git branch -m published master
git push -f origin master
```

> Making master have what you want people to use, and do all other work in branches.

(a "`git-symbolic-ref HEAD refs/head/published`" would not be propagated to the remote repo)

This is similar to "[How do I delete origin/master in Git](https://superuser.com/a/749412/141)".

---

As said in [this thread](http://www.nabble.com/0.0-branch-in-eAthena-renamed-to-master-td20799674.html): (emphasis mine)

> "`git clone`" creates only a single local branch.
> To do that, it looks at the `HEAD ref` of the remote repo, and creates a local branch with the same name as the remote branch referenced by it.
>
> So to wrap that up, you have repo `A` and clone it:
>
> - `HEAD` references `refs/heads/master` and that exists
>   -> you get a local branch called `master`, starting from `origin/master`
> - HEAD references `refs/heads/anotherBranch` and that exists
>   -> you get a local branch called `anotherBranch`, starting from `origin/anotherBranch`
> - HEAD references `refs/heads/master` and that doesn't exist
>   -> "`git clone`" complains
>
> **Not sure if there's any way to directly modify the `HEAD` ref in a repo**.

(which is all besides the point of your question, I know ;) )

---

*Maybe* the only way would be a ["publication for the poor"](http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2007/09/11/git-server-for-the-poor-git-update-server-info-rsync-and-remote-repository/), where you:

```
 $ git-symbolic-ref HEAD refs/head/published
 $ git-update-server-info
 $ rsync -az .git/* server:/local_path_to/git/myRepo.git/
```

But that would involve write access to the server, which is not always possible.

---

As I explain in "[Git: Correct way to change Active Branch in a bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302018/6309)", [`git remote set-head`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) wouldn't change anything on the remote repo.

It would only change the remote tracking branch stored locally in your local repo, in `remotes/<name>/HEAD`.

---

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git remote  set-head`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/39149df36426ee106367c701feb5a8c8662c9f74/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L98)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-headem))</sup>" that failed still said something that hints the operation went through, which was misleading.

See [commit 5a07c6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a07c6c3c2723297f1fbf18e3abcf0cd26e02293) (17 Sep 2020) by [Christian Schlack (`cschlack`)](https://github.com/cschlack).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 39149df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39149df36426ee106367c701feb5a8c8662c9f74), 22 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a07c6c3c2723297f1fbf18e3abcf0cd26e02293): don't show success message when `set-head` fails
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Schlack</sup>

> Suppress the message 'origin/HEAD set to master' in case of an error.
>
> ```
> $ git remote set-head origin -a
> error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
> origin/HEAD set to master
> ```

Comment: Thanks, VonC. I read that before posting here. But as you can see, a branch called "master" is unwelcome in this project for technical and policy reasons.

Comment: You could then enforce that policy by  disallowing any update on master branch through a pre-commit hook.

Comment: Yes, if it turns out that there is no way to do what I want then I will do exactly that and accept your answer. Thanks for following up!

Comment: Thanks for the update. For the moment, I used the "no-common-ancestor" trick to make a master branch with only one commit. (I.e.: git branch -D master; echo ref: refs/heads/master > .git/HEAD; rm *). Then I just touched a file called GO_AWAY, and commit message explains the situation. That will work for now. I may check through the source and track down where the receiving side sets HEAD for a final answer.

Comment: This gave me a 'non-fast-forward' error. The only way I was able to do it was using the answer here: http://superuser.com/a/749412/399381

Comment: @ctn That is simply because I forgot the `-f` (`--force`) option. I have edited the answer accordingly. Then answer you reference does use that same option.

Answer (score 54):

**Update:** This only works for the local copy of the repository (the "client"). Please see others' comments below.

With a recent version of git (Feb 2014), the correct procedure would be:

`git remote set-head $REMOTE_NAME $BRANCH`

So for example, switching the head on remote `origin` to branch `develop` would be:

`git remote set-head origin develop`

Comment: Does this feature need recent version of git on the server or is it enough if client machine has recent git installed?

Comment: @Totor is terse but right; this answer should be downvoted. Git has this somewhat confusing concept of a "local, default branch for the remote". It lets you type "origin" instead of "origin/defaultbranch" and is a *pure client-side* thing. Long story at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote #set-head

Comment: to confirm what @MarchH is talking about: run `git checkout -b default; git push origin HEAD; git remote set-head origin default`. You can then inspect the local changes with `cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` (it should be `ref: refs/remotes/origin/default`), and the lack of remote changes with `git remote show origin` (it will still be whatever it was before you added the default branch).

Answer (score 36):

Since you mention GitHub, to do it on their site simply go into your project, then...

`admin > Default Branch > (choose something)`

Done.

Comment: Excellent! That was the last missing bit.

Comment: My origin/HEAD already points to a feature branch instead of master. I tried changing "main branch" back and forth, but it did not affect the HEAD...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Settings > Branches > Default Branch

Comment: Changing the default branch in Gitlab/Github, does NOT change the `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` pointer

Answer (score 24):

See: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-symbolic-ref.html

This sets the default branch in the git repository.  You can run this in bare or mirrored repositories.

Usage:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<branch name>
```

Comment: $ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/name-of-branch

Comment: I did this in my remote repo and it fixed my problems cloning where for some reason the head was another branch name and therefore trying to clone master would result in an error whilst trying to close master in composer, this might be very specific to this scenario, but others might be in that position and wondering what to do

Answer (score 11):

(There was already basically the same question "[create a git symbolic ref in remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847609/create-a-git-symbolic-ref-in-remote-repository)", which received no universal answer.)

But there are a specific answers for various git "farms" (where multiple users can manage git repos through a restricted interface: via http and ssh): http://Github.com, http://Gitorious.org, http://repo.or.cz, [Girar](http://en.altlinux.org/Git.alt) (http://git.altlinux.org).

These specific answers might be useful for those reading this page and thinking about these specific services.

- Now they have a drop-down menu for selecting the HEAD branch at **http://repo.or.cz** (example: http://repo.or.cz/editproj.cgi?name=for-me-and-for-all_imz.git);
- and at **http://gitorious.org**, too (look somewhere in the settings);
- and at **http://GitHub.com**: admin > Default Branch > (choose something) (thanks to @srcspider's answer);
- Since [v2.6](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/v2.6/Documentation/rest-api-projects.txt#343), the default branch can be set in the [Web interface under 'Projects' > 'List' >  > 'Branches'](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#default-branch). In v2.12, Gerrit [added a new set-head command](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+log/v2.12/Documentation/cmd-set-head.txt) that can be [used over ssh](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-set-head.html).
- and in **[Girar](http://en.altlinux.org/Git.alt)** (running on http://git.altlinux.org to build packages for ALT's distro), one can the ssh interface for this:

  `$ ssh git.alt help | fgrep branch
  default-branch <path to git repository> [<branch>]
  $`

  for example `ssh git.alt default-branch packages/autosshd.git sisyphus` to change the HEAD in the remote repo `autosshd.git` to point to the `sisyphus` branch.

Comment: Now they have a drop-down menu for selecting the HEAD branch at http://repo.or.cz (example: http://repo.or.cz/editproj.cgi?name=for-me-and-for-all_imz.git ) and http://gitorious.org , too. Great!

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to the remote repo from a shell, just go into the .git (or the main dir if its a bare repo) and change the HEAD file to point to the correct head.  For example, by default it always contains 'refs: refs/heads/master', but if you need foo to be the HEAD instead, just edit the HEAD file and change the contents to 'refs: refs/heads/foo'.

Comment: I have admin rights on Git server and i did exactly the same. We use Gitolite and i went to the repository which i created. The directory name is `myrepo.git`. The content of HEAD file in the given directory was changed from `ref: refs/heads/master` to `ref: refs/heads/mainline`. Now, when i try to clone the repository on my local box, it still points to master. I ran `git clone ssh://gitolite@git.server/myrepo` command. Any idea for such behaviour?

Comment: Git server version: `git version 1.7.1` & Git client version: `git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2`

Answer (score 6):

You can create a detached **master** branch using only porcelain Git commands:

```
git init
touch GO_AWAY
git add GO_AWAY
git commit -m "GO AWAY - this branch is detached from reality"
```

That gives us a **master** branch with a rude message (you may want to be more polite).  Now we create our "real" branch (let's call it **trunk** in honour of SVN) and divorce it from **master**:

```
git checkout -b trunk
git rm GO_AWAY
git commit --amend --allow-empty -m "initial commit on detached trunk"
```

Hey, presto!  **gitk --all** will show **master** and **trunk** with no link between them.

The "magic" here is that **--amend** causes **git commit** to create a new commit with the same parent as the current HEAD, then make HEAD point to it.  But the current HEAD doesn't have a parent as it's the initial commit in the repository, so the new HEAD doesn't get one either, making them detached from each other.

The old HEAD commit doesn't get deleted by **git-gc** because refs/heads/master still points to it.

The **--allow-empty** flag is only needed because we're committing an empty tree.  If there were some **git add**'s after the **git rm** then it wouldn't be necessary.

In truth, you can create a detached branch at any time by branching the initial commit in the repository, deleting its tree, adding your detached tree, then doing **git commit --amend**.

I know this doesn't answer the question of how to modify the default branch on the remote repository, but it gives a clean answer on how to create a detached branch.

Comment: You can create a detached branch easier by fetching an unrelated branch from another repo and giving it a name. For example, `git fetch git:user@example.com:foo remote-branch-name && git checkout -b detached-branch FETCH_HEAD` will add new branch `detached-branch` that matches the branch `remote-branch-name` in remote `git:user@example.com:foo`. Of course, the "remote" can be a repository in local file system you have previously prepared.

Answer (score 6):

Related to the question, I ended up here when searching for:

**How do I make a local repo aware of a changed default branch on GitHub**

For completeness, adding the answer:

```
git remote set-head origin -a
```

Comment: `git remote set-head origin <branch>`

Answer (score 2):

First, create the new branch you would like to set as your default, for example:

`$>git branch main`

Next, push that branch to the **origin**:

`$>git push origin main`

Now when you login to your GitHub account, you can go to your repository and choose Settings>Default Branch and choose "**main**."

Then, if you so choose, you can delete the master branch:

`$>git push origin :master`

Comment: The key point to understand is that if you hosting provider (GitHub in this example) does not provide a method for modifying default branch, you're out of luck. Git protocol does not provide a feature to modify the remote default branch; you would need to be able to run `git symbolic-ref` on the remote shell or otherwise able to modify text file called `HEAD` in the remote repository root directory.

Answer (score 0):

For gitolite people, gitolite supports a command called -- wait for it -- `symbolic-ref`.  It allows you to run that command remotely if you have W (write) permission to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

The best and straight-forward way to change git remote HEAD is to run

```
git remote set-head origin DEV
```

origin is usually the remote name
DEV the remote branch name

Answer (score -1):

Simple just log into your GitHub account and on the far right side in the navigation menu choose **Settings**, in the **Settings Tab** choose **Default Branch** and return back to main page of your repository that did the trick for me.

Comment: While it shows the new branch as the default in the GitHub interface, when doing a git clone [repo], I'm not getting that branch. i.e. .git/HEAD contains the wrong ref.