# Difference between HEAD and master (or main)

Tags: git, github

What is the difference between the `HEAD` and `master` in Git?

I did a clone of a project on GitHub and want to push my changes to the remote. But to which one should I push?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 181):

`master` is a reference to the end of a branch. By convention this is usually the main integration branch, but it doesn't have to be. (As of [git v2.28.0](https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/), released in July 2020, the default name changed from `master` to `main`)

`HEAD` is actually a special type of reference that points to another reference. It may point to `master`/`main` **or it may not** (it will point to whichever branch is currently checked out). If you know you want to be committing to the `master`/`main` branch then push to this.

Here is a visual example:

[image]

On your own repository you can check where the `HEAD` is pointing to by running this:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

However, finding out where the `remotes/origin/HEAD` is pointing to is more tricky because it is on the remote machine.

There is a great little tutorial on git references [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111126114417/http://people.gnome.org/%7Efederico/news-2008-11.html)

Comment: +1 More precise answer than mine. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository/3302018#3302018 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository for illustrations around those concepts.

Comment: Note: `HEAD` doesn't necessarily refer to a branch; the "dreaded" detached head occurs when `HEAD` refers to a commit that is *not* a branch head.

Comment: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/
It is now `main` not `master`.  Too many pending edits to change the text.

Answer (score 55):

The simple answer is that `HEAD` is a pointer/label to the most recent commit of the branch you are currently on. `master` is the default branch created when you initialized a git repository (e.g. `git init`).

You can delete the `master` branch (e.g. `git branch -D master`). You cannot delete the `HEAD` pointer.

Comment: "`HEAD` is a pointer/label to the most recent commit of the branch you are currently on." I think this is misleading at best. If you checkout an older commit, then HEAD is now a pointer to that older commit, not to the most recent commit. Right?

Comment: You are correct. HEAD is your latest checkout. But in my defense, for Git, the `checkout` command is the equivalent to switching branches in other common SCM systems.

Comment: I sympathize... I could easily have made the same mistake. The only reason I noticed was because I'm at the stage of trying to research what HEAD really means. Any chance you could edit your answer to be correct? I find HEAD to be a difficult concept to find accurate descriptions of, for git non-experts like myself. And having advice sitting out there on the web that gives *incorrect* information about HEAD makes it quite a bit harder.

Comment: I think your comment is a fantastic clarification for anyone seeking a finer understanding of what the Git `HEAD` pointer really is.  I appreciate your comment and think others will too. My original post's content along with your followup comment complement each other. Thanks.

Comment: A technicality, but if you checkout an older commit, you are no longer 'on' a branch.  If you checkout a commit instead of a branch, you have what is called a "detached HEAD", you are no longer 'on a branch'.  Being 'on a branch' means your HEAD is referencing a branch, and by definition you are on the most recent commit of that branch.  Just because you have commit 'b54fe7' checked out, and master points to that commit, doesn't mean you're on the master branch.  There could be several branches pointing to the same commit, you're 'on' the one that HEAD is pointing to, if any.

Comment: "master" doesn't refer to the default branch name in this context. It's a reference.

Answer (score 8):

Simply push the changes of your current branch

```
git push origin
```

and it will push your branch '`B`' changes to '`origin/B`'.
If you are on your `master` branch, git will push to `origin/master`.
Actually it will push all changes on the local branches that have matching remote branches at `origin`. It is controlled by the config setting **[push.default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/git-push-current-branch/948397#948397)**.
See also [pushing RefSpecs in the Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch9-5.html#pushing_refspecs).

---

What you are seeing is the sidebar representing all the refspecs of your remote repo in the [Experimental GitX fork](http://brotherbard.com/blog/2010/03/experimental-gitx-fork/) of the [GitX project](http://gitx.frim.nl/).

[image]

The `HEAD` will designate the default branch for that remote.
See [`git remote set-head` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

> Having a default branch for a remote is not required, but allows the name of the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific branch.
>   For example, if the default branch for `origin` is set to `master`, then `origin` may be specified wherever you would normally specify `origin/master`.