# Does HEAD always refer to what "master" refers to (in this context)?

Tags: git

Suppose one is on branch "master" and that HEAD is at the tip of the branch (say, on commit `C`).  Suppose one then executes `git reset --hard HEAD^3` back to commit `A`.  Then HEAD now refers to `A`.

**Question:** Does "master" also refer to `A`, or is it still pointing at `C`?  Put differently: in this context, does HEAD *always* refer to what the branch "master" does (i.e., assuming that our repository has only one branch named "master")?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between HEAD and master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386959/difference-between-head-and-master)

Comment: Put simply, the answer is no. Take a look at this question, I think the accepted answer explains the difference between "master" and "HEAD" pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386959/difference-between-head-and-master

Comment: What commits are between `A` and `C`? `git reset HEAD~3` puts you back *three* commits behind, so you probably want four commits in your example: `A -- B -- C -- D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check it, current branch is:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

current state of the repo:

```
$ git log --oneline
e585b43 C
4bbf8be B
6ae7d39 A
fb4949b Initial commit
```

Let's rebase it:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~3
HEAD is now at fb4949b Initial commit
```

Let's check where HEAD points:

```
$ git log HEAD  --oneline
fb4949b Initial commit
```

Let's check where master points:

```
$ git log master --oneline
fb4949b Initial commit
```

As you can see `HEAD` and `master` point at the same commit

Comment: So master doesn't persist in referring to the tip of the branch, in this case commit C?  Doesn't that conflict with joran's answer?

Comment: *`HEAD` and `master` point at the same commit.* Again, that's imprecise. `HEAD` points at `master`, which itself points at commit `fb4949b`, but `HEAD` does not point directly at commit `fb4949b`, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

No, HEAD will not always refer to the same commit as "master".
In case you checkout a commit that has been become dangling HEAD will refer to that commit and "master" will still refere to the tip of that branch.

In this case will `git reset --hard HEAD~3`change HEAD and master to refer to the same commit.