# Git Commit Log graph - confused

Tags: git

I am a relatively newbie to GIT and having issues understanding Commit Log graph. 
I am under the feeling that each parallel line is a branch.While my source has only 2 branches..I see 3-4 parallel lines in the commit log graph provided below(Microsoft Team Services).Can someone help me understanding this?

[image]

Comment: Those connections aren't branches, just references to one or more parent commits. Branches are just pointers/labels to specific commit references.

Comment: Tags are pointers to specific commits, a branch _name_ describes commit which is currently the _end_ of the branch.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. Each parallel line is a branch.

In the example image that you gave above those 7-character strings are (short versions of) commit IDs.

For ease of explaining I am going to include this graph (below) that I found online; particularly because it shows the order of the commits, the first commit, and the last commit.

[image]

**Listing of the branches**

In this graph there are four branches. They are:

1. `master branch` (represented by the purple dots)
2. `next branch` (represented by the green dots)
3. `feature-1 branch` (represented by the pink dots)
4. and `feature-2 branch` (represented by the orange dots)

The line between commit ID 1b43a59 and commit ID 2b59872, and including commit ID 5f357ab and commit ID 3c5bf63, is the `master branch`.

The line between commit ID 1b43a59 and commit ID 1ce9df1, and including commit ID dff00dd, is the `next branch`.

The line between commit ID 1b43a59 and commit ID 5f357ab, and including commit ID 9ffab9f and commit ID 9db9694, is the `feature-1 branch`.

The line between commit ID 1b43a59 and commit ID 3c5bf63, and including commit ID 54a16ed and commit ID 813c45b, is the `feature-2 branch`.

**Listing of the merges**

The  `feature-1 branch` is merged into the `next branch` at the commit represented by commit ID dff00dd.

The  `feature-1 branch` is merged into the `master branch` at the commit represented by commit ID 5f357ab.

The `feature-2 branch`is merged into the `master branch` at the commit represented by commit ID 3c5bf63.

The `feature-2 branch`is merged into the `next branch` at the commit represented by commit ID 1ce9df1.

The `next branch` is not merged into anything.

Answer (score 1):

In git, branches are names of so called "heads" – they are related to the top most commits (which – in a simple case – do not have any further, or child, commits). In your case currently you have one branch, but previously there were 4 branches (at the moment of `4e31eddd`), then 3 branches (`d9effc23`), and so on until it became one branch at `09d65a15`.

However, even if a branch is merged into another branch it can still be a "head".

Comment: Is there a command where I can get to know the name of those branches.?

Comment: A `git branch -a` shows you all current branches both existing locally and remotely.

Comment: Are all branches "heads"?

Comment: Yes, more precisely: branch names are pointers to branches ends or "heads". More details can be found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196544/what-are-the-git-concepts-of-head-master-origin and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386959/difference-between-head-and-master.