# git branch merging

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'm going through a tutorial and it said this command, "git branch -a" would list all my remotes, both local and remote. So i did that and this is what i got.

```
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:releventz davidadams$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/flashdrive/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:releventz davidadams$
```

Master is the branch i'm currently on and is green. All three remote branches are red. I had a little trouble when i was trying to get the path right to my remote to add and push to. Could that be a reason i have three remote branches instead of just one? I just added 'flashdrive' as my remote and pushed to it. So i know that's the most recent but what are the other two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`origin` is the default name of the git remote repository from where you clone your local repository.

- `remotes/origin/master`: the `master` branch from the `origin` repository.
- `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`: the `HEAD` branch, a kind of branch that represent *the current branch** (in fact that's not true but it's a little more complicated, see [What is HEAD in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly))

Obviously, the last branch, is a remote `master` branch, located on the remote repository you just added.

Comment: so are "remotes/origin/master" and "remotes/origin/HEAD" one and the same currently?

Comment: Currently yes. Imagine you have a local bugfix branch, and a remote origin/bugfix branch, when you `git checkout bugfix`, origin/HEAD would be, by default, origin/bugfix, allowing you to do `git push bugfix:origin/HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

> I just added 'flashdrive' as my remote and pushed to it. So i know that's the most recent but what are the other two?

Note that your local branch master isn't currently tracking a remote master branch (either `remotes/flashdrive/master` or `remotes/origin/master`).
That can lead to an issue with latest git1.8.0: "[Git 1.8.0: fatal: The current branch master has multiple upstream branches, refusing to push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030714/git-1-8-0-fatal-the-current-branch-master-has-multiple-upstream-branches-refu)"

`remotes/origin/HEAD` is a symbolic HEAD that [you can change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository/3302018#3302018).
See "[How does `origin/HEAD` get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841024/6309)".

> `origin/HEAD` represents the default branch on the remote, i.e. the HEAD that's in that remote repository you're calling origin.

When you clone your repo, you will checkout by default the branch that your current `remotes/origin/HEAD` is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more information on your remote repositories by running

```
git remote -v
```

This will list the repositories and where they actually are.