# No remotes/origin/HEAD with gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm pretty new to git, but I've been playing around with it on a remote server I set up and I'm pretty sure that I understand the basics.

I just set up gitlab and pushed some of my code to a new project on it. What I did was:

1. Get all my code in a directory
2. git init
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "Initial commit"
5. git push origin master

Where origin was set up with:

```
git remote add origin git@1.2.3.4:myproject.git
```

Now when I do git branch -a I see:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Whereas when I was playing around before, I always saw:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I understand that the head is a pointer the currently checked out branch, so shouldn't it exist on the origin? Why wasn't it created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't worry much about this remote `HEAD`. This line is simply artifact of the way original clone works, and represents state of remote's `HEAD`.

It can be considered as a default branch that is preferred by server (even on remote bare repository) - it will be checked out by your client `git clone` by default if `-b branch` option was not used.

Your local file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` probably contains string `ref: refs/remotes/origin/master` now. You can remove it if you want (not that I recommend doing it, mind you), and `git branch -a` will not show it anymore.

Except for this usage of remote `HEAD` as default branch for first clone, for you state of remote `HEAD` never matters. You should only worry about state of real remote branches, not remote `HEAD` as it only makes sense for remote state as its default selected branch. And if remote is bare repository, it does not make much sense even on remote.

And the reason why you did not see remote HEAD when you did `git remote add ...`, `git fetch`, `git pull` is because in that case git did not have to make a decision on which default remote branch to pickup by default.

Answer (score 4):

You can set it by command `git remote set-head origin -a`, which automatically set origin/HEAD to point to appropriate remote branch. Or using `git remote set-head origin <branch>` to specify a remote branch to point.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841024/1851492

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem in this way

1. First delete the index file in the `.git` folder.
2. Then open terminal and type `git reset`