# How can I fetch remotes/origin/HEAD?

Tags: git

I'm writing a script that will delete remote branches that are already merged into the default remote branch, but I'm having trouble determining the remote default branch because it isn't always set.

I know if I clone a repo, then I get a tracking branch to `remotes/origin/HEAD`

However, if I add the remote to an existing repository and fetch, then I won't get this remote tracking branch.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13599727/4233593) asks why it isn't there, but I want to know how to add it.

Comment: Why do you want to set the remote's HEAD?  There's some options for setting the remote HEAD in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master

Comment: @Alex, I'm not trying to set it, I'm trying to fetch it.

Comment: Gotcha.  How about this one then:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958/how-does-origin-head-get-set  The second answer works in my limited test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [alexbclay implied in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396401/how-can-i-fetch-remotes-origin-head#comment66119479_39396401), there seems to be no real use for this, but there are several ways to find it:

- If your Git is new enough (and the one on the server is as well), `git ls-remote --symref` will print it out (plus everything else, so you might want to add more options to limit the output):

  ```
  $ git ls-remote --symref
  ...
  ref: refs/heads/master  HEAD
  ...
  ```

  Once you have this, you can create the reference locally with `git symbolic-ref` (in this case, assuming remote `foo`, using `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/foo/HEAD refs/remotes/foo/master`: follow the usual renaming, using `git config --get-all remote.foo.fetch` to figure out the renaming, if it's non-standard).
- If that fails, you can fall back on the method `git clone` uses: read the remote heads (with `git ls-remote` again) and see if there is a unique match on the ID for `HEAD` against all the actual branch heads.  If it's unique, you know which one it is.  If not, you can pick the first alphabetically as `git clone` does, or pick one at random.  (I'm not sure off-hand what `git clone` does if the remote's `HEAD` is detached and thus does not match any of the remote's branches.  It might be interesting to find out.)
- Slow but simple: make a new clone, see what you get for `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`. :-)  That's basically the previous two methods glommed together.  (Use `--reference` to speed up the network interaction, perhaps.)

Comment: Thanks torek, `git ls-remote --symref <remote>` is exactly what I was looking for. I have updated my question to provide a hint about why I needed this.