# How to get main git branch name from command-line?

Tags: git, terminal, command

How to get main branch name from command-line/terminal?

I know that the main branch is called `master` by default, however one can rename it to anything they want.

PS—It would be nice to get the name of the local *and* remote main branch.

**Edit:** What I call `main branch` others might call `default branch` or `stable branch`. It’s the one into which you (should) merge everything (stable/working) into.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as a "main branch"  because for git all branches are just the same... pointers to revisions, and they can be called anything.

Comment: eftshift0 is correct. [There's no such thing as a "main branch"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25446978/354577).

Comment: **See Also**: [How to get default branch name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28666357/1366033)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no deep knowledge of `git`, however, in `git`, there is usually `{remote}/HEAD`, e.g. `origin/HEAD`. Here’s an excerpt from the [man page of `git remote`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```sh
 set-head

    Sets or deletes the default branch (i.e. the target of the
    symbolic-ref refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD) for the named remote.
    Having a default branch for a remote is not required, but allows
    the name of the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific
    branch. For example, if the default branch for origin is set to
    master, then origin may be specified wherever you would normally
    specify origin/master.
```

From this I understand that the `{remote}/HEAD` is the main/default branch of the `{remote}`. One could get the name of the branch using this (does anyone know a better/plumbing command?):

```sh
git branch -r | grep -Po 'HEAD -> \K.*$'
origin/master
```

When one wants to get the local main/default branch, there usually is no `HEAD` branch, however usually there’s one and only branch that tracks the `{remote}/HEAD`, which name we can get using (again, there surely is a better command):

```sh
git branch -vv | grep -Po "^[\s\*]*\K[^\s]*(?=.*$(git branch -rl '*/HEAD' | grep -o '[^ ]\+$'))"
master
```

Of course, one need to `set-head` if it is not already set, in order to have a ‘`HEAD`/master/main branch’ in the output of `git remote -r`. Therefore, we need to run the following command once prior to using the above commands (thanks for pointing this out @pixelbrackets).

```sh
git remote set-head origin -a
```

---

**Update:**

Recently, I wanted to get some more information (some commands I’ve got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171550/find-out-which-remote-branch-a-local-branch-is-tracking)):

```sh
# Get currently checked out local branch name
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
# Output: branch

# Get remote branch name that is tracked by currently checked out local branch
git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' "$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)"
# Output: origin/branch

# Get local main branch name
git branch -vv | grep -Po \
  "^[\s\*]*\K[^\s]*(?=.*$(git branch -rl '*/HEAD' | grep -o '[^ ]\+$'))"
# Output: master

# Get remote branch name that is tracked by local main branch (AKA the remote HEAD branch)
git branch -r | grep -Po 'HEAD -> \K.*$'
# Output: origin/master
```

Comment: This answer only works if the origin shows a `HEAD`. This might not be the case. To set it up run `git remote set-head origin -a` (source stackoverflow.com/a/52062124/3894752). Then the given command `git branch -r | grep -Po "HEAD -> \K.*$"` will work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

If you assume that the main branch will either be called `master` or `main`, here is what I do to quickly detect the main branch name in a local repository:

```
git_main_branch () {
    git branch | cut -c 3- | grep -E '^master$|^main$'
}
```

Then other commands I have that need to know the main branch name can use it. For example I have `gc-m` which stands for "git checkout main branch":

```
alias gc='git checkout '
alias gc-m='gc $(git_main_branch)'
```

Comment: I’d rather don’t want to assume anything.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use something like this:

```
alias gc-m='git checkout `git branch -rl "*/HEAD" | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev`'
```

Comment: Thanks, @LuisDavim! (1) I could shorten your command to `alias gc-m='git checkout "$(git branch -rl '*/HEAD' | grep -o '[^/]\+$')"'`.

Comment: (2) I currently use `git checkout "$(git branch -vv | grep -Po "^[\s\*]*\K[^\s]*(?=.*$(git branch -r | grep -Po 'HEAD -> \K.*$').*)")"` for the same purpose (certainly, it could be shortened and potentially optimalised), but there is one big difference between your command and my command: first I get the remote main branch (e.g. `origin/master`) and then check which local branch is tracking that remote. Although it usually is not the case, a user _might_ change the local branch name (or set a different branch to track the remote main branch) and then your command wouldn’t work.

Comment: (3) I tried to update my command with the yours (shortened by me) and it is longer by a single character: `git checkout "$(git branch -vv | grep -Po "^[\s\*]*\K[^\s]+(?=.*$(git branch -rl '*/HEAD' | grep -o '[^ ]\+$'))")"`.

Answer (score 2):

you probably want to use this command `git branch -r`, `-r` is for list remote branches only, if you want to list both uses `-a`.
Normally the master branch point to `origin/HEAD` something like this `origin/HEAD -> origin/master`

Comment: I think this answer shows me a _way_ to deal with this. It’s the `HEAD` ref, which I believe to be only one in a repo. Am I wrong?

Comment: I was wrong: there are as many `HEAD`s, as many branches. (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049827/how-are-the-terms-head-head-and-tip-different)

Comment: If `git branch -rv` does not list a HEAD on origin, then it may be set up using `git remote set-head origin -a` (source https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062124/3894752).