# git log decoration origin/HEAD

Tags: git, git-log

I have two project repositories.

When I run `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` in each, one shows `(HEAD, origin/dev, origin/HEAD, dev)` and the other shows `(HEAD, origin/dev, dev)`.

In both cases, `dev` is the default branch. Why does `origin/HEAD` show in one and not the other? What does one do to make `origin/HEAD` appear or not appear?

Comment: How were the repositories created?

Comment: Have you run `git fetch origin` in both repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention in "[How does `origin/HEAD` get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841024/6309)", it is set automatically on `git clone`.

That means:

- either your second repo wasn't cloned (but initialized empty, added a remote and fetched)
- or there was some rebase which makes origin/HEAD not visible.
  Try (to see *all* commits) a: `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all --branches`

Comment: Thanks! Never used it before, but `--all` is handy, and totally explains what happened (indeed, origin/HEAD had just moved elsewhere).

Comment: also strange that when searching for old answers, I didn't see that question that you linked to.