# origin/HEAD points to wrong branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

still getting used to git, using source tree as the Git client.

I have a Git repo that has the master branch checked out.

I had two clones of this repo.

Today origin/Head magically appeared in one of them.

So I cloned the repo again to see if origin/HEAD would appear again, it did.

In the new repo origin/HEAD points to origin/master, as I would expect.

In the original repo origin/HEAD points to a different branch. ie origin/my_branch.

What could have happened to make origin/HEAD appear?
From what I have read origin/HEAD should point to the checked out branch in the origin, why would it be pointing to a different branch?

How can I make origin/HEAD point to where I think it should be pointing?
Can I remove origin/HEAD without making changes to the origin?
should I not care and ignore this inconsisitence?

have I got this all totally wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If I had forced the initial check out to be origin/my_branch would I see this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [`git remote set-head`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), `origin/HEAD` is the default branch (i.e. the target of the symbolic-ref `refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD`) for the named remote.

You can remove it without changing the remote repo itself, since it is a *local* reference to your remote default branch.

See "[How does origin/HEAD get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841024/6309)".

It can be set/updated with a `git remote set-head origin -a`, which is what you need to do to update it in your first repo.
It is set automatically on a `git clone`.