# What is the significance of the active branch in a bare git repository?

Tags: git, git-bare

When I tried to delete a branch in a bare repo, I was told that I can't because I'm "currently on it". A bit surprising, as I expected not to be on any branch in a bare repo.

Which branch should be active in a bare repo used as the central repository to cause minimal side-effects? Is the active branch merely a vestige from non-bare repos?

Before bare repos I had a "dummy" branch checked out, now I'm wondering if I should still have a "dummy" branch active on my central bare repo.

Answer (score 4):

Bare repos has a symbolic `HEAD` reference which points to a default branch, usually `master`. Whichever branch `origin/HEAD` points to is the default branch that's checked out for any clones of that bare repo. See [How does origin/HEAD get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841024/456814).

Also, from the [official Linux kernel docs for `git-remote`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

> ```
> set-head
> ```
>
> Sets or deletes the default branch (i.e. the target of the symbolic-ref `refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD`) for the named remote. Having a default branch for a remote is not required, but allows the name of the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific branch.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean the HEAD branch on the bare repo? This just gives a clue to new clones which branch is considered the default to checkout when cloning for the first time. It's fairly inconsequential.

Comment: @romkyns that's not the error message I get when trying to delete `master` in a bare repo, can you show us your full delete command and error message please? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: @Cupcake - did you mean to reply to me here?

Comment: romkyns actually had another comment here earlier, but it looks like he deleted it.

Comment: That's right. There was no mention of "active" anywhere, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

To cite the [`git clone` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

> `--branch <name>`
>   `-b <name>`
>
> Instead of pointing the newly created `HEAD` to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s `HEAD`, point to `<name>` branch instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out. `--branch` can also take tags and detaches the `HEAD` at that commit in the resulting repository.

So basically you keep `HEAD` in the remote repo pointing to whatever branch you'd like your clones to make the default one.  No need to keep a dummy branch.