# Link `origin/HEAD` back to `origin/master`

Tags: git, github

Lost reference to `origin/HEAD`.

When I execute command `git branch -r`, I see just these branches.

```
git branch -r
  origin/master
  origin/some-other-branch
```

How can I get `origin/HEAD` linked back to `origin/master`

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
origin/some-other-branch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally set it with:

```
git remote set-head origin master
git remote set-head origin -a
```

But it is supposed to be set on the upstream repo itself (and in your local repo when cloning the upstream repo).
See "[How does `origin/HEAD` get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8839958/6309)".

That means, it remains a local setting to your local repo, and has no influence on the actual HEAD of the upstream repo (hence the `-a` option to get it from the upstream repo itself).

See more at "[Change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485590/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote set-head origin -a
```

credited to Robert Siemer [How does origin/HEAD get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958/how-does-origin-head-get-set/29405808#29405808)