# git : remote HEAD is ambiguous - how to push changes to another branch than the cloned one?

Tags: git, branch, clone

I cloned a remote rep, **master** and made some changes. Before pushing changes admin has created **Development** branch.

Now "**git remote show origin**" command is showing the following ambiguous HEAD branch.

```
  HEAD branch (remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following):
    development
    master
  Remote branches:
    development new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    master      tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

I already made changes to cloned **master**. Now, how to push changes to the newly created **Development** branch ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: This problem has been corrected in Git 1.8.4.3. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25430727/2541573. You should update your Git installation, if possible.

Comment: @Jubobs (and @Chandu): note that both local and remote must be new enough (1.8.4.3 or later) so that they can use the new message to identify HEAD correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a local branch called `development` "linked" to the remote `development` branch, from your current state (eg : your `master` branch with extra commits), run :

```
# create a new branch on the current commit, and switch to it :
$ git checkout -b development  

# push your moidifcations to the remote "development" branch,
# and tag your local branch to follow the remote "development" branch :
$ git push --set-upstream origin development
```

---

If you want to push to any remote branch :

```
git push origin mylocalbranch:remotebranch
# for example :
git push origin master:development

# if you add '-u' or '--set-upstream', your local branch will
# follow the remote branch :
git push -u origin mylocalbranch:remotebranch
```