# HEAD in `git branch -r` output

Tags: git

I am confused about HEAD pointer in the `git branch -a` output, which is not explained in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

- I have an origin repository with a `master-branch` and a branch `nipunbatra-patch-1`.
- I have another remote repository `NILMTKtoENERGYTK`.
- My local repository has a `master`branch and a `my-branch`to which I want to add the changes from the `NILMTKtoENERGYTK` repo.

[image]

Why is there only a HEAD label in the `origin` repo and neither in the `NILMTKtoENERGYTK` nor in the local repo? And which implications does it have for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `HEAD` is a symbolic reference to the `origin` remote's default branch, i.e. the branch that gets checked out when doing a `git clone`. While it's common for remotes to have that symbolic reference, it's not required, and some remotes might not have defined it on the server side.

Comment: Is it really about beeing 'defined' or not? I turned arround the order of the two remote repositories. `NILMtoENERGYTK`becomes the origin and the previous origin is added as additional remote. In this case again only the origin, the repo without the HEAD pointer before, has this HEAD pointer. So it must have some meaning!?

Comment: Well, on the initial `git clone` your local `remotes/origin/HEAD` is set to whatever the server-side's `HEAD` points at, if any. But you can change your local `remotes/origin/HEAD` manually afterwards, like you probably did. Also see the documentation for [git remote set-head](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-headem) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958/how-does-origin-head-get-set).

Comment: `set-head` is what I was looking for. If I set the HEAD manually it does also show up in the `git branch -a` output.