# How to interpret the brackets in the git log?

Tags: git, command-line

Running `git log` gives me an output like this:

```
commit 69b6309f09365c09a2fe10f09aee801d1fae29ee (HEAD -> master, edeviserBranch)
Author: eDeviser <eDeviser@xyz.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 2 09:53:07 2019 +0200

    added foo

commit 59a08270fb730db259a8d5819bb585a613024d97 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: eDeviser <eDeviser@xyz.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 2 09:49:50 2019 +0200

    More Text
```

I don't understand the meaning of the content inside the brackets. What is the meaning of the text inside the brackets? Is this the branch which is the commit based on? If yes, what is the difference between `HEAD -> master`, `origin/master` and `origin/HEAD`?

**How to interpret the brackets in the git log?**

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer**

It is a list of pointers which are pointing to the corresponding commit. I recommend you read about `HEAD` and `origin`.

**Commits and pointers**

In `git`, you have commits and pointers moving in between those commits. A branch is just a pointer which points to a commit. Say you have a branch `mybranch`, then `mybranch` is just a pointer. If you commit on that branch, the pointer `mybranch` just moves on to that commit.

**The HEAD pointer**

`HEAD`: the `HEAD` pointer points to the current commit your repo is on. In your case, it is pointing to commit `69b6309f09365c09a2fe10f09aee801d1fae29ee`, that is: your repo is now on commit `69b6309f09365c09a2fe10f09aee801d1fae29ee`. The content in parenthesis is a list of other pointers which point to the same commit as `HEAD`, which, in your case are `master` and `edeviserBranch`. From that information, you can see that `master` and `edeviserBranch` have not diverged yet. You probably pushed the last commit with text `added foo` onto `master` and then created a new branch `edeviserBranch` from `master`.

**The working area**

`origin`: the default name that `git` gives to your remote repo. With `origin/<pointer>`, you can access branches in your working area. The working area is a space between your local and remote repositories. `git fetch origin` downloads the data from your remote repo to the working area of your local repo. It doesn't merge any data, it just downloads it. An example to make the concept of working area clear:

```
git fetch origin # update data from remote origin.
# For example, your remote branch edeviserBranch will be downloaded to your working area
# and can be accessed from origin/edeviserBranch.

git checkout master # go to your local master branch
git merge origin/edeviserBranch # merge branch edeviserBranch from your working area
# to your local master branch
```

**The origin/HEAD pointer**

`origin/HEAD`: a pointer in your working area which points to the default commit that will be checked out by someone cloning your repository.

According to the output of `git log`, pointer `origin/master` and `origin/HEAD` both point to commit `59a08270fb730db259a8d5819bb585a613024d97`.

If your working area is not synchronized with your remote repo, and you execute `git fetch origin` (and doing so, you update your working area with your remote repo), those pointers will change.

Comment: Many, many (actually all that I have found) references use "working directory" or "working tree" or "working area" to mean the files and folders on our local machine in the same folder as .git and certainly not in/under .git

As for the origin files/folders fetched.  I have not found documentation with good names for that space, but one person calls them local remote

Comment: I agree, I actually do the same since a while. But if I'm not mistaken, I think the working area was described as in this answer by a previous version of git doc (not sure). Local remote is very clear though.

Answer (score 4):

They indicate at which commits the various branch pointers in your repository are currently.

`HEAD -> master` means that this is the `HEAD`, i.e. current working directory, which happens to belong to the `master` branch.

`edeviserBranch` shows that your current local branch `edeviserBranch` is also pointed at that same commit.

`origin/master` at your previous commit means that the remote of your branch `master` is still at that previous commit, i.e. your remote master is one commit behind your local repository.

`origin/HEAD` is the default branch/commit that will be checked out by someone cloning your repository anew [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958/how-does-origin-head-get-set)

Comment: origin/master is the master branch in the working area, NOT directly the remote branch master. Someone else could update master on the remote repo. Then, your origin/master would not point to that new commit (unless you do git fetch).

Comment: True, it doesn't point to the actual remote commit, but it doesn't point to the current working area either, `HEAD -> master` already does that.
Instead I mean that it points to the last commit which is known to be on `origin`

Comment: I am confused by your last comment. origin/master points to master on origin in the working area. Head and master (local repo) is not the same as origin/head and origin/master (working area).

Answer (score 1):

HEAD remembers the branch location
HEAD-> master is where you work

The latest commit of the current branch
If you move (check out) a branch, the HEAD position will change

The location of the remote repository where you are
remotes / origin / HEAD-> origin / master // HEAD location