# How to change which remote branch HEAD points to?

Tags: git, branch, head

There are LOTs of answers pertaining to this on SO but none of them seem to work for me.

I'm using git ver. 2.25.1.

```
git remote show origin
```

shows:

```
 remote origin   Fetch URL: /opt/ideatree   Push  URL: /opt/ideatree  
 HEAD branch: dotImport   
 Remote branches:
     dotImport      tracked
     getProdWorking tracked
     master         tracked   Local branch configured for 'git pull':
     master merges with remote master   Local ref configured for 'git push':
     master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Local is fine.  It's the "HEAD branch: dotImport" that I'm trying to alter, to "HEAD branch: master".

Since 'dotImport' is not the main branch eventually I will want to delete it on remote, but that can't happen as long as HEAD is set to dotImport:

```
git push origin --delete dotImport
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
```

Attempting to re-assign HEAD:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
```

has no effect.

```
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

yields:

```
origin/HEAD set to dotImport
```

It just won't budge.

Here's another view of what it looks like on the remote, which disagrees with what 'git remote show origin' says:

```
 git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/dotImport
  origin/master
```

Maybe I'm missing a step which updates the remote with HEAD changes made locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers I'm reading on SO (answers to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578) or [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958) for example) seem to indicate it can't be done -- not through `git` alone from a clone of the remote.

You should see if you can access the central repo (if you have a self hosted gitlab server for instance) and change `HEAD` from the central repo itself, or go through the web GUI (for github.com for instance) to set the "default branch" for your project.

Answer (score 0):

The URL for `origin` is `/opt/ideatree`.  This has no "scheme" part (no `https://` or `git://` or `ssh://` in front), so it's just a local file: your Git software, on your machine, will call up Git software on ... your own machine.  It will call itself!  It will ask itself—another instance of itself—to `cd /opt/ideatree`, where it should find another Git repository.

It is this *other* Git repository, over in `/opt/ideatree`, that has branch `dotImport` checked out.  That produces these error messages (from the "other" Git—the second Git instance, running in `/opt/ideatree`):

> ```
> error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
> 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
> ```

These error messages get relayed to your own Git, which sticks the word `remote:` in front of each line, resulting in the two lines you see.

> Here's another view of what it looks like on the remote, which disagrees with what 'git remote show origin' says:
>
> ```
>  git branch -r
>   origin/HEAD -> origin/master
>   origin/dotImport
>   origin/master
> ```

How did you obtain this view?  (If you got it by running `git branch -r` locally, in your own clone, be aware that `-r` shows what your clone has at the moment, not what the remote has at the moment.  Running `git fetch` updates what your clone has, except that it doesn't update `origin/HEAD`; to make that happen you must run `git remote origin set-head --auto`.)  It does indeed disagree with what your `git remote show origin` said, and also with the error message you got.

You should, given appropriate permissions at least, be able to:

```
cd /opt/ideatree
git checkout master
```

to switch `/opt/ideatree` to branch `master`.  But if `/opt/ideatree` is itself meant to be the *target* of `git push` operations, it's usually wisest to set it up as a *bare* repository: one with no working tree at all.  In this case, nothing is checked out, which means no branch can be worked-on, which means any branch name can be pushed-to (though the `HEAD` branch cannot be deleted, which means you want to use the `git symbolic-ref` command to adjust it if you ever decide to use `main` instead of `master` for instance).  All of this just happens over in `/opt/ideatree` though; once you're done there, you `cd` back to the place where you do your work.

(If you want to be able to do a push-to-deploy, you'll need some additional glue code.  Git makes a poor deployment system, but I don't have any other system to recommend.)

Comment: Basically this restates the problem then gives the solution that @leGEC gave, but thanks.

Comment: Um, no: I point out that the "remote" is mounted locally, so you can do what you need to *locally*, and also point out that you're setting yourself up for future unhappiness. Whether these extra details are *useful* is up to you.

Comment: Having remote on the same machine is intentional.  And it was set up as a bare repository.

Comment: You did not mention either of these in your question. If you had, my answer would have been: *Just `cd /opt/ideatree` before running `git symbolic-ref`.*