# What is the use of the origin/HEAD branch?

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)

By default we see two branches in git:

```
origin/master
origin/HEAD
```

I wonder, what is head used for?

Comment: The Git Community book says that it is a pointer to your current branch. Source: http://book.git-scm.com/1_git_directory_and_working_directory.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate of [HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/964876/456814), this deals with `HEAD` in remotes, not a local repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HEAD doesn't point to the current branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24176052/456814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HEAD and ORIG\_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HEAD` is a a symbolic reference (similar to a symbolic link) that points to the branch you're on. You can get the reference it points to using `git symbolic-ref HEAD`. If you switch branches (e.g. `git checkout branch1`), `HEAD` will point to that. This is stored in a file in `.git` as `.git/HEAD`.

`master` is a local branch that you can work on. It's usually the default if you clone a repository or start a fresh one.

`origin/master` is the location of the `master` branch on the `remote` called `origin`.

Comment: HEAD in a local repository does not always refer to a branch, it more specifically refers to the currently checked-out branch. You can enter a detached HEAD state where HEAD no longer refers to any branch.

Comment: Correct. I didn't mention that because it's not *that* common and the OP's question suggested her lack of experience with git.

Comment: It's funny though, even [the documentation itself](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) says that HEAD refers to the current branch. The documentation is wrong `:/`.

Comment: That is in some ways true. Even in a detached head state, you are somewhere and that can be referred to as a head (which is what git says for branch) but yeah, you're right. Send them a pull request?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer to the current commit.

Since it represents a commit you can can use it with most of git's commands.

#### Examples:

Show the latest commit with it's diff:

```
git show HEAD
```

Interactively rebase to the commit before the latest:

```
git rebase -i HEAD^
```

Comment: HEAD ***does not*** refer to your current ***branch***, it refers to the currently checked-out commit. You can check-out a commit directly, which puts you in a "detached HEAD" state (detached from a branch). If you checkout `HEAD~10` for example, HEAD will then refer to a commit that's 10 commits behind your previous branch.

Comment: Thanks @Cupcake, I've updated my answer appropriately.