# What parts of git have special / default behaviours for a branch named "master"?

Tags: git, branch

Given that there's [no wide agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397427/what-should-the-master-branch-contain-in-git) on [the semantics of `master`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133156/when-using-git-is-using-the-master-branch-for-active-development-advisable), we're considering having no branch named `master` at all on our `origin` server.

What are the consequences of that in terms of defaults that are built in to the standard `git` command line client?  How does it treat a branch named `master` differently from other branches -- both locally and on the remote?

Comment: As far as I know, other than actually defaulting a new repository to having a branch named master that is also "checked out" (as far as one can consider it being checked out in an empty repository), there is no special handling of this branch name at all.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25449034/6309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my survey of the codebase and my experience with repositories that don't have a `master` branch, I'd say you're in the clear.

At worst, the are a couple of edge cases where not being explicit will cause a command failure instead of falling back to a `master` branch.

---

- `git clone` sets up a `master` branch by default when no remote refs are found and the `--bare` flag wasn't specified ([builtin/clone.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12039e008f9a4e3394f3f94f8ea897785cb09448/builtin/clone.c#L1187))
- `git fast export` with the `--anonymize` flag leaves `master` alone, since it's a well-known default and doesn't communicate anything ([built-in/fast-export.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12039e008f9a4e3394f3f94f8ea897785cb09448/builtin/fast-export.c#L463))
- merge commit messages are customized based on the target branch (i.e. "Merge branchx" vs. "Merge branchx into branchy") ([builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69d71ec4433d21f464d83b529432856da2387bba/builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c#L459))
- `git init` uses `master` as the default branch name ([builtin/init-db.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c2c7d17b030646b40e6764ba34a5ebf66aee77af/builtin/init-db.c#L230))
- `git submodule` defaults to `master` when a branch name isn't specified ([builtin/submodule--helper.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12039e008f9a4e3394f3f94f8ea897785cb09448/builtin/submodule--helper.c#L1681))

(the `git-remote.c` and `files-backend.c` outputs from below don't actually interact with the `master` branch)

---

The list above was compiled by using the following `git grep` on the [git repository](http://github.com/git/git).

```
# Look for string literals within *.c files containing "master" 
# with 10 lines of context, excluding the t/ and contrib/ directories
$ git grep -C 10 -E -e \".*master.*\" -- :**/*.c :^t/ :^contrib/
```

Answer (score 1):

`master` is used as a default in some places.

- The first branch in an empty repository is done ino the `master` branch.
- Merge commit messages either are "Merge branch x" or "Merge branch x into y" when y != `master`

But besides of this kind of stuff a branch named `master` is not really necessary.