# git packfiles no source code

Tags: git

I am new to using git, and so apologize I'm missing something that should be obvious from the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles).

I would like to view the source code of a project after a `git  clone`, but all `git-clone` does is download a `.pack` files in `./objects/pack`.  How do you extract a `.pack` into the source code files?

What is the output path of [git unpack-objects](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-unpack-objects.html)?

Comment: Have you tried checking out a branch to the working directory?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166) (the one you are cloning) is empty, you should see the content of its default branch ([usually master, unless its symbolic-ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository/3302018#3302018) has set to point to am empty branch) in your working tree:

```
 git clone url/repoA
 cd repoA
 git branch # to see in which branch you are
```

Only git clone --bare would generate an empty working tree (since it would only create a git directory repoA.git, and no working tree at all).

Answer (score 0):

you might also try this to start a new 'develop' branch off the master:

```
git checkout develop
```