# Our git repository has a branch called HEAD

Tags: git, git-branch

I recently noticed that our git server has a branch called HEAD. I've tried doing this locally and git warns me that this is ambiguous. Are there any potential horrible problems we could encounter by deleting/renaming this branch?

Comment: You should ask the person who made the branch :)

Comment: that person is long gone :( There's nothing special on the branch (there's even another branch at the same point!) I just want to know if GIT would have a seizure if I tried deleting HEAD.

Comment: Note: With Git 2.16, a branch named HEAD won't be possible anymore (at least, you won't be able to create new ones). See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581080/6309)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server *should* have a branch pointer called `HEAD`, which will point to your default branch. By default, `git branch -r` will show you this:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain any of the horrible consequences that might arise from calling a branch "head."

Comment: That's because this answer assumes that nobody has done such a thing, and that OP is misinterpreting the output of `git branch -r`.

Comment: @meagar's right that i misunderstood the output. However, it is possible to create a branch called head, not sure how dangerous it is though.

Comment: Calling a branch "head" should be fine as long as you're not on Windows. If you are then you're dOomED. I don't want to know what happens when you try to make the branches doom, Doom, dOom, doOm, dooM, DOom, DoOm, DooM, dOOm, dOoM, doOM, DOOm, DOoM, DoOM, dOOM and finally DOOM on winDOOMS.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for a bare repo to have a 'HEAD'.  Keep in mind that HEAD is not a normal branch, but rather it is a pointer to a branch.

1. For a non-bare the 'HEAD' "branch" is points to the [checked out branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304106/11296).
2. For a bare repo, it points to the default branch, i.e. the branch checked out as the working dir when the bare repo is cloned to a non-bare repo.  Often it points at "master", but you can [point it to a different branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository).

Answer (score 2):

Creating a remote branch called `HEAD` is possible, and does not seem particularly harmful:

```
~/code/foo/bar (master) $ git push origin master:HEAD
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:foo/bar
 * [new branch]      master -> HEAD
~/code/foo/bar (master) $ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD
  remotes/origin/master
~/code/foo/bar (master) $ git push origin :HEAD
To git@github.com:foo/bar
 - [deleted]         HEAD
~/code/foo/bar (master) $ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Creating a *local* branch called `HEAD` has nastier effects:

```
~/code/foo/bar (master) $ git checkout -b HEAD
Switched to a new branch 'HEAD'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
~/code/foo/bar (HEAD) $ git checkout -b fubar
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'HEAD'.
~/code/foo/bar (HEAD) $ git branch -a
* HEAD
  master
  remotes/origin/master
~/code/foo/bar (HEAD) $ rm .git/refs/heads/HEAD
~/code/foo/bar (HEAD*) $ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

All of the above was with git version 2.3.0 installed via Homebrew on OS X.

It is easy to type many of the above invocations by accident, and <strike>unfortunately Git does not fail fast when `HEAD` (or `FETCH_HEAD`) is specified in a place where the special meaning does not apply.</strike> Edit: Newer versions of Git do now fail fast with `HEAD`. For example, with git version 2.22.0:

```
~/code/foo/bar (master) $ git checkout -b HEAD
fatal: 'HEAD' is not a valid branch name.
```

But a branch called `FETCH_HEAD` is still allowed.

Comment: This answer currently suggests `rm .git/refs/heads/HEAD ; git co -b fubar`. If you do those commands one after the other, `fubar` will be created while your working directory is still in the state corresponding to now-deleted-branch-`HEAD`, and with no history, which is almost certainly not meaningful. I think this answer should suggest `rm .git/refs/heads/HEAD ; git checkout master` as a way of getting back to solid ground, instead.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Fair enough; I changed it accordingly. I also added a note about newer versions of git, which no longer allow creating a local branch called HEAD.

Comment: I still managed to create a local branch named HEAD by accident: `git fetch origin HEAD:HEAD`.  With tab completion enabled `H<Tab>` completed to `HEAD:HEAD`.