# Git HEAD points to an old branch

Tags: git

I have an repository in which the `master` branch was renamed to `product`. Things are fine except on one box where the code was cloned before this change. On that box `HEAD` still points to master:

```
* local-2
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/local-1
  remotes/origin/product
  remotes/origin/local-2
```

It's certainly incorrect, but in practical application, it's also causing an issue with a deployment script. What would it take to reposition `remotes/origin/HEAD` so that it points to `remotes/origin/product`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines of output:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/product
```

say that the reference `HEAD` in your origin repo points to `origin/master`, but as you've said, `origin/master` has been renamed to `origin/product`.  You'll need to do two things to correct this:

1. Make the reference `HEAD` on `origin` point to `product`.
2. Update local clones to have `remotes/origin/HEAD` point to `origin/product`.

For step #1, if your `origin` is hosted on GitHub, you simply set the default branch for `origin` to `product`. If it's not hosted on GitHub, you'll need access to the remote repo, from which you run the following:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/product
```

For step #2, you'll need to run the following on each local clone to update what they have the remote repo `HEAD` configured to:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/product
```

See also:

1. [Official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git symbolic-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-symbolic-ref.html).
2. [Git: Correct way to change Active Branch in a bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository/3302018#3302018).
3. [How do I change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides “master”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master/1485590#1485590).