# Pull all branches from remote through it's mirror bare remote

Tags: git

There is a bare remote (let's call it `group_origin`).
I made a bare mirror clone of it (`my_origin`).
I `git clone my_origin` to a repository with a working directory (`my_rep`).
In `my_rep` I code, push to `my_origin` and pull from `my_origin`.

When `group_origin` is updated by my colleagues, I git fetch `my_origin` from `group_origin`.
I see tags of the kind `group_origin/branch_1` (when I execute `git log` inside of `my_origin`). Thus, `my_origin` is "aware of" newly created branch `branch_1` on `group_origin`.
However, when I `git pull my_origin` from `my_rep` and `git log` within `my_rep` later, I don't see any notice of `branch_1`.

So, my question is:
how can I update `my_rep` from `my_origin` (which is in turn a bare mirror of `group_origin`) to fetch newly created branches of `group_origin/branch_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the tracking branches in `my_origin` for each and every branches from `group_origin`.

For that, I use [that one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309) from the question "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379081/6309)".

```
remote=origin ; for brname in `git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD | awk '{gsub(/[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do git branch --set-upstream-to $brname  $remote/$brname ; done
```

Otherwise, by default, `my_origin` will only declare one branch (the default one from `group_origin`, [referenced by its `symbolic-ref HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302018/6309)).
And, in turn, `my_rep` will see only that one branch.

---

The other option is to add a remote to your local repo `my_rep`, for monitoring `group_origin` directly.
(You can add as many remote [upstream repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) that you want or need, just to have a look at their history)

```
cd my_rep
git remote add group_origin /url/to/group_origin
git fetch group_origin
```

That way, you will see those `group_origin/branch_x` and can decide to create one and push it to `my_origin`.

```
git checkout --track -b branch_x group_origin/branch_x
```

Comment: Just curious, Is it an accepted/good practice to bare clone another bare repo?

Comment: @ansh0l If you need to push to that intermediate repo, then that intermediate repo better be a bare one indeed, so it may be uncommon, but not a "bad" practice.

Comment: @VonC, thanks! The only thing is that on my git version I had to replace --set-upstream-to to --set-upstream in that one-liner.

Comment: @user1541776 then you must be using a old git version ;)

Comment: @user1541776 more specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002239/difference-between-git-checkout-track-origin-branch-and-git-checkout-b-branch/10002469#10002469 You must be using a git previous to 1.8.0 (like the default one on Ubuntu). If so, use an up-to-date ppa like https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa.

Comment: @VonC, thank you for the comment. That's correct, I used the old one 1.7