# Set HEAD for a bare repository

Tags: libgit2sharp

I don't know how to set the `HEAD` reference for a bare repository.

Throw the `BareRepositoryException` with message

`Additional information: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Repository (BareRepo).`

when I trying `repo.Checkout(repo.Branches["balabala"])`

Comment: This question is about when you are using `libgit2sharp`. For anyone coming here looking for how to set `HEAD` for a bare repository on the command-line or on a git hosting service, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302018/260122 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962737/260122.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking out will indeed update update the `HEAD`, but also update the current content of the workdir with the content of `Commit` being checked out.

This indeed doesn't work with a bare repository as there's no working directory.

The correct way to move the `HEAD` in a bare repository is to update the target of this reference:

- `repo.Refs.UpdateTarget(repo.Refs.Head, repo.Refs["myBranch"])` will update the `HEAD` to make it point to the branch `mybranch` while keeping it **attached**
- `repo.Refs.UpdateTarget(repo.Refs.Head, repo.Refs["myBranch"].Tip.Id)` will update the `HEAD` to make it directly to the commit at the tip of the branch, thus **detaching** the `HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

fine, I found `repo.Refs.UpdateTarget("HEAD", repo.Branches["master"].Tip.Sha)`, it's working.