# Git remote head refers to feature branch instead of master

Tags: git, version-control

Prior warning, I'm a bit of a Git newbie, so sorry if some of this is in distinctly non-tech speak (or I just use the wrong terminology).

Last week I noticed a bit of an oddity on my company's Git repo, it appears that the remote HEAD has been moved from pointing at master to pointing at a feature branch instead.

So, it used to be

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/featureBranch1
remotes/origin/featureBranch2
remotes/origin/master
```

and is now

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> featureBranch1
remotes/origin/featureBranch1
remotes/origin/featureBranch2
remotes/origin/master
```

I cloned the repo into anew, and sure enough, the default branch that was cloned was `featureBranch1`, not `master`.

The feature branches on this project generally have a lifetime of a week or two, and in the next few days, `featureBranch1` is going to be merged into `master` and deleted.

Being a Git newbie, I'm not entire sure what the effects of the remote HEAD pointing to that branch will be, if any, so what I'd like to know is is this an issue, and if so, how much of one?

Will the feature branch merge and delete ok? Will this cause issues with the repo if the remote HEAD branch is deleted? Will it automatically revert to `master`? Will we all be given a day off because no one can do any dev work?

We're using Git version 2.9.3.windows.2.

(Note: I'm also vaguely interested in how this happened, seeing as developers don't generally have permissions to change anything on the server, but that's less important at the moment than any possible knock on effects)

Comment: This *is* a duplicate, mostly, but there are many possible links; here are 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958/how-does-origin-head-get-set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository/3302018#3302018 Note that unless your Git (server and/or client) are very old, predating 1.8.4, some parts of some answers no longer apply.

Comment: @torek I did have a read of those before posting this, but none of them seemed to answer what the effects of the default remote branch being deleted will be. I've added the Git version into the question.

Comment: Hm, you're right, none of them go into quite the right detail. Basically, the effect on any existing clone is "none at all". The effect on *new* clones is that Git may not know what to check out, and in extreme cases, will check out nothing at all.  (The server's version matters too, but if they're all 2.0 or later you're fine there.)

Comment: @torek Great, thanks, so basically, it won't break anything too badly :) If you want to make than an answer, I'm happy to mark it as such (and the repo was set up on the server about 2 months ago, so it'll be whatever version was the most recent then)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to find a suitable duplicate and didn't.

The short answer is that `git clone` will still work, but might become slightly annoying.  See the example below.  Any existing clone will be unaffected.

The complete answer is a bit complicated as there are two Gits involved, and hence two Git versions, and the primary effect is only on `git clone` run from a client.

#### What is `HEAD`, really?

First we should establish what `HEAD`, in any Git repository, is and represents.  Literally, `HEAD` is just a file, usually containing a *symbolic reference*<sup>1</sup> to some existing branch:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

However, `HEAD` may be "detached", in which case it contains a raw hash ID.  It's also possible for `HEAD` to point to a non-existent branch name:

```
$ git checkout --orphan newbranch
Switched to a new branch 'newbranch'
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/newbranch
```

and yet there is no branch named `newbranch` yet.  If we now `git checkout` some other branch, the name `newbranch` vanishes entirely, as if it had never existed.

This gives us the definition for what `HEAD` is: **`HEAD` provides to Git the notion of the current branch.**  This is usually a branch name, and that branch name is usually a valid reference: `.git/refs/heads/master` exists and contains a valid hash ID, or else `.git/packed-refs` contains an entry for `refs/heads/master`, for instance.  Alternatively, it may be a raw commit hash, meaning that the current branch has no name and is based on the current commit (whose ID is in `HEAD`).

When `HEAD` is a symbolic reference, it simply contains the name of another reference (and this is further constrained to be only a *branch* reference).  Git actually allows *any* reference to be symbolic, but only `HEAD` is really useful (if you make non-`HEAD` symbolic references, they act all weird,<sup>2</sup> to use a highly technical description :-) ).

#### How `git clone` chooses a branch to check out

The syntax for `git clone` includes the `-b` option:

```
git clone -b <name> <url>
```

This tells Git to connect to the URL, download everything needed into the new clone, and then, in the new clone, run `git checkout <name>`.  The `<name>` part need not actually be a *branch* name—tags are accepted here—but usually it is a branch name.

If you *omit* the branch name, Git chooses some branch to check out, but—*which one?*  The answer is that *your* Git attempts to consult the *other* (server) Git to find out what branch *its* `HEAD` names.  This is where Git versions matter.

In some old versions of Git (those predating 1.8.4.3), Git does not know how to ask for, or tell to another Git, anything about any symbolic references.  Instead, an old server tells about, or an old client asks for, the hash ID for `HEAD`.  If `HEAD` contains a raw hash ID or a valid branch name, the server and client will be able to communicate the corresponding ID.  The client then uses a quick and dirty method to *guess* at the server's branch name: it looks for any branch that has the *same* hash ID.

As long as both client and server are newer, though, the client will ask for, and the server will send, the actual branch name.  As long as that branch name is valid, the client will be able to use it.

If all of these steps go as planned, the client will run:

```
git checkout <name>
```

as expected.  Since the client also just *cloned* the server's `refs/heads/<name>` to `refs/remotes/origin/<name>`,<sup>3</sup> the client *has*, e.g., an `origin/master` and can make a new local `master` pointing to the same commit.

But—**here's the answer to the primary question**—if the server's name is *not* valid, the client simply gives up and creates a `master`, though not in quite the right way:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/nobranch
$ git clone [url-obscured] tt
Cloning into 'tt'...
remote: Counting objects: 122, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Total 122 (delta 42), reused 99 (delta 34)
Receiving objects: 100% (122/122), 24.79 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (42/42), done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.

$ cd tt
```

(note: the blank line—the extra newline—really is in there).

```
$ ls
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
$ git branch -a
  remotes/origin/branch
  remotes/origin/foobranch
  remotes/origin/master
```

Note that there is an `origin/master` but `git clone` did not check it out correctly.<sup>4</sup>

This somewhat-bogus `master` is an "orphan" branch, i.e., is one of those not-yet-existing branches: our new clone has a `HEAD` that says `ref: refs/heads/master` but there is no `refs/heads/master` yet.  Hence, we can get fix things by checking out any branch.  In an odd quirk, even `git checkout master` works:

```
$ git checkout master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Already on 'master'
```

Weird, no?  The first output line tells us Git has just created the `master` branch, then the second one tells us that Git did nothing and checked out nothing.  But in fact Git filled in the index and work-tree too:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

and now we have all our files.

---

<sup>1, 2</sup> In very early versions of Git, symbolic references were actually just symbolic links to the "real" reference file.  This is where all the weird behavior of symbolic references comes from: they all act *exactly like* symbolic links on Unix/Linux systems.  So it's not actually weird at all, except that it's pure mechanism, instead of practicality.

<sup>3</sup> You can change the `origin` part with another command line option, but that changes both halves of this equation the same way, so that the result is the same.

<sup>4</sup> This is because `git clone` has the core `git checkout` code built in to it, but not quite coded the same way as `git checkout` itself.  It does not *literally* run `git checkout master`.  If it did, it would have discovered that `origin/master` exists and would have behaved sensibly.  A future Git might fix this otherwise-trivial bug, of course.

---

#### What about `remotes/origin/HEAD`?

(This part actually *is* a duplicate, but I include it here for completeness.)

Everything in `refs/remotes/origin` is just your client's way of remembering what it saw on the remote named `origin`.  This is also true of `origin/HEAD`, but in a rather peculiar way.

Note that above, we did not get an `origin/HEAD`.  This is because the client could not figure out the server's `HEAD` (since I deliberately broke it).  If I repair the server's repository and re-clone, things go a bit more smoothly:

```
Cloning into 'tt'...
remote: Counting objects: 122, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Total 122 (delta 42), reused 99 (delta 34)
Receiving objects: 100% (122/122), 24.79 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (42/42), done.
$ cd tt
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/branch
  remotes/origin/foobranch
  remotes/origin/master
```

Now we have a symbolic reference, `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, pointing to `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  (Git abbreviates these, though the amount of abbreviation is inconsistent.  Use `git branch -r`, and Git drops `refs/remotes/`; but use `git branch -a`, and Git drops only `refs/` from the left hand side, yet still drops `refs/remotes/` from the *target* of the symbolic reference.)

**All of this happens only during cloning.**  Once the clone is done, the symbolic ref `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is essentially fixed, unless you explicitly update it yourself, on your own client.  You may do this at any time by running:

```
git remote set-head origin
```

and this particular command takes a bunch of options:

- `-a`, `--auto`: your (client) Git calls up the other (`origin`, in this case) Git and goes through the same query process it would use for cloning.  Whatever symbolic name it figures out, your Git changes your `origin/HEAD` to match.
- `-d` or `--delete`: your (client) Git deletes the symbolic reference.
- A name: your (client) Git attempts to resolve this name to a remote-tracking branch currently in your own repository, for this particular remote (again, `origin` in this case).  If it finds one, your Git sets the symbolic reference to that remote-tracking branch.

You can also use a Git *plumbing* command (not really meant for humans to run directly) to set or delete `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  This bypasses all the normal checking, so you can set it to something nonsensical, or to "detach" it (point it directly to a commit), neither of which `git remote set-head` allows.

#### But what *good* is `origin/HEAD`?

The thing about `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is that it's not really useful for anything.  You have these various ways to have it set or to change it in your clone, and yet, the only thing it does is let you use the name `origin` to refer to whatever remote-tracking branch `refs/remote/origin/HEAD` refers to.

This is actually just step 6 of the six-step name-resolving process described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Since `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is a symbolic reference, and `origin` matches `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` through step 6, Git replaces this with the target of the symbolic reference (such as `refs/remotes/origin/master`) which is the corresponding remote-tracking branch.  (This then resolves to a commit hash ID if appropriate, which is usually the case.)

In essence, this saves typing out `/HEAD`: you could have written `origin/HEAD`, which would resolve at step 5 of the six-step sequence.  But you don't have to type in the `/HEAD` part, because step 5 is followed by step 6.

Comment: Bl**dy hell, I was expecting a paragraph, maybe two at most. This is awesome, thank you for taking the time to write it all out.