# Rename git branch 'master' to 'main' on bare repository without beeing on GitHub

Tags: git

I have a bare git repo on a server with the default branch called `master`.
I want to change the name to `main`.

When I search for instructions I am always told to change the `default` branch on GitHub to the new `main` branch before deleting the `master` branch.
But my repo is not on GitHub.
When I try to delete the `master` I get this error message:

```
$ git push origin --delete master
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To server:projects/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'server:projects/repo.git'
```

What I did so far:

```
$ git branch -m master main
$ git push -u origin main
```

How can I delete the `master` branch and set the `main` branch as new default so that future `git clone` won't result in an empty directory checked out?

Comment: You need to dell your server which branch to consider to be the main branch. How this is done depends on which server software you are using.

Comment: Create the main branch, check it out and delete the master branch.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution which worked for me here:
[Git: Correct way to change Active Branch in a bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository)

As I have access to my bare repo on the server I did:

```
[server:~/projects/repo.git]$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main
```

Then on my local copy I could `git push origin --delete master` without error.

A new `git clone` of this repo checked out all files and the `main` branch as default.