# Git Config file and setup not allowing pull from github and push to dreamhost

Tags: git, github, ssh

### .git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:myusername/wp-theme.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = dreamhost
    merge = refs/heads/main
[remote "dreamhost"]
    url = ssh://myusername@server.domain.com/~/my.domain.com.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dreamhost/*
```

I am having a hard time pulling my code from github and pushing it to my dreamhost server.

I run (on my local computer)...

```
 git push -u dreamhost main
```

and then run (on the server)..

```
git clone ~/my.domain.com.git ~/cloned.my.domain.com.git
```

However the folder is empty.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your empty cloned repository folder `~/cloned.my.domain.com.git`, check the output of:

```
git branch -avv
```

The idea is: your local computer might have a recent Git, with a default branch of `main`.
While your target bare repository (`~/my.domain.com.git`) might have as default branch `master`.

If you push the `main` branch, but, on the target side, clone the default `master` branch, the latter would have no commit/file to show.
You would need to go back to the bare repository (`~/my.domain.com.git`), and [change its default branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302018/6309).

If `origin/main` is present:

```
git checkout main
```

Comment: I get "  remotes/origin/main 8a1c8e0 Commit for add all wp files", so it sees the last git commit, but does not display the files. if I do just "git branch" it shows nothing.

Comment: @user2012677 Then start with `git switch -c main`, and see of the files are restored.

Comment: Got this error: "git: 'switch' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."

Comment: @user2012677 Well done. If you upgrade git, you will get git switch, less confusing than checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309 (Git 2.23, Q3 2019).