# Python poetry Failed to clone verify ref exists on remote

Tags: python, git, python-poetry

I am using poetry 1.4.0 on ubuntu 22.04, and trying to add a specific git branch into my project :

```
poetry add git+ssh://git@dev/home/git/projects/jaydebeapi#nanosecond_fix

Failed to clone ssh://git@dev/home/git/projects/jaydebeapi at 'nanosecond_fix', verify ref exists on remote.
```

This is strange because manual git clone works :

```
git clone -b nanosecond_fix ssh://git@dev/home/git/projects/jaydebeapi
Cloning into 'jaydebeapi'...
remote: Counting objects: 1592, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (572/572), done.
remote: Total 1592 (delta 879), reused 1592 (delta 879)
Receiving objects: 100% (1592/1592), 397.30 KiB | 4.14 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (879/879), done.
```

Any idea ?

NOTE : GIT version is 2.34.1 on both server and client

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Comment: Maybe an issue with Poetry's internal git client. You could disable it via the [*`experimental.system-git-client`*](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#experimentalsystem-git-client) config setting, and see if it improves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case, as in [issue 835](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/835#issuecomment-1192533388), verify the remote branch does exist.

The manual clone you have done would check out by default the `main` branch, not a '`nanosecond_fix`' branch.

Inside your manual clone, though, you can list all local and remote branches:

```
git branch -avv
```

If the branch exists, you can [switch branch in a bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302018/6309):

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/nanosecond_fix
```

Comment: Inside my manual clone the branch `nanosecond_fix` does exist (seen with branch -avv command)

Comment: @Eric Does `origin/nanosecond_fix` exist?

Comment: origin/nanosecond_fix does exist

Comment: @Eric Then updating Git might be a good idea indeed.

Comment: I just did it : both client and server are now 2.34.1 but still the same thing ... Am now debugging by putting some traces in poetry...

Comment: I tried `git remote set-head origin nanosecond_fix` but it did not work. But If I edit the `HEAD` file in the remote repository and put `refs/heads/nanosecond_fix` instead of `refs/heads/master` then it works.

Comment: @Eric Instead of that, can you try `git switch nanosecond_fix`

Comment: @ VonC : git switch does not work on a remote bare git repository.

Comment: @Eric Then using [`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/mybranch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302018/6309) would be the preferred option, rather than editing directly some file.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your dependencies pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
repository_name = { git = "git@github.com/myorganization/myprivaterepo.git", branch = "master" }
```

Comment: I had already tried with branch="nanosecond_fix" (the banch I wanted) but the message is the same.

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your sentences. This would be gentle to your readers.