# difference between fork and branch on github

Tags: github, branch, git-branch, git-fork

If I fork a project that's hosted on github. Do I fork all the branches? How do I know which branch my fork is based on? In other words which branch will be downloaded to my PC?

Comment: Simple English explanation: 
A branch is like a fork which is from a parent fork.
A fork is like a branch which lacks a parent branch.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All branches on GitHub will be copied in a fork. (Obviously, this doesn’t include branches that were never pushed to GitHub in the first place.)

But a fork is a GitHub-to-GitHub operation; nothing is copied to your PC.  It’s not quite the same as a Git *clone*.  If you mean to ask “what’s copied when I clone a project?”, see the manual for [`git-clone(1)`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

Answer (score 171):

Think of it this way:

**The repo[sitory]** corresponds to the collaborated work of the team across one or many branches. All contributors have their own copy of it.

Each **fork** of the main repo corresponds to a contributor's work. A fork is really a Github (not Git) construct to store a clone of the repo in your user account. As a clone, it will contain all the branches in the main repo at the time you made the fork.

Each **branch** within the fork and/or in the main repo can correspond to several kinds of things, depending on how you want to work. Each branch could refer to a version of the project but can also correspond to different channels of development, like hotfixes or experimental work.

The **pull request** (in the GitHub ecosystem) corresponds to the task. Every time I want to contribute an isolated finished task to the main repo, I create a pull request corresponding to the **commits** made in that task. These commits are pulled from either my **fork** or my **branch** to the **main repo**.

A **commit** is a set of changes to the code. This is one of the most interesting things about Git. You don't transfer files, you transfer logs of changes.

Comment: liked how you explained all the relevant related bits like pull request mapping to fork/branch. "you dont transfer files, you transfer logs of changes"... i already knew that but this phrase is perfect!

Comment: plus-one for clarifying that fork is a github, not git. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Fork is a clone on the GitHub side (it clones everything).
When you are cloning a repo, you are getting the all history of said repo, with all its branches.

Even though you can in theory [change the default branch of a remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master), a clone from a GitHub repo mainly look for the master branch. Meaning to change the "default" branch a GitHub clone will get, you need to rename the master branch.

Comment: So when I clone the forked repo (download it to my PC effectively), al the branches are on my PC? But in one branch extra files have been added. So will my PC have those files or not?

Comment: @Jonathan: your PC will get all branches with all files. But your *working directory* (the space where you checkout *one* of those branches) will actually the only space where you will see those files.

Comment: SO wherre will the other files actually be stored in the .git folder?

Comment: @Jonathan: as loose or packed objects, see http://book.git-scm.com/7_how_git_stores_objects.html (objects being a blob (your "files"), a tree, a commit or a tag: http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html )

Answer (score 4):

If you fork a project, you are making a copy of the whole project to your git hub account. you are not coping anything to your PC

To make a copy in your PC you have to clone it and pull all the stuff and you will got all branches & code of that project

Answer (score 3):

This can be explained very well. You have a central repository at GitHub. Whenever you take a clone of it on your personal computer to do some changes, this local clone of the main repository is called a fork.

The branch is something different and is included in the fork/repo. Actually the branch is your work at different stage of development. They are created as and when required to save a set of functionalities, to give access to different users, to demonstrate the site to client, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a fork of a project from the Github website, you get all the branches from the upstream project.

If you clone from your newly minted fork to your local PC, you will have the `origin` remote on your PC pointing to the master branch of your fork on Github.

Comment: According to the Help.GitHub page [Forking a project](http://help.github.com/forking/), creating the `upstream` branch is something you have to do; and they tell you how to do so.

Comment: That is a remote, not a branch.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share a real life example of **when we use Branches and when we use Forks**

We have GitLab at our shop and sometimes we have to work on packages from a Laravel project. We normally create a branch and push changes to the branch that we have been testing in our local VM dev environment when working with the actual Laravel project.

Let's say our project is located at

```
https://github.com/yardpenalty/mainproject.git
```

**Branch usage:**

Lets say the branch is called `It_doesnt_matter`

Once we have our branch the way we want for production we then make our final push to this branch and **create a merge request** which then goes into UAT for testing.Once the test has went through QC the changes are merged into production.

The **merge** from the `It_doesnt_matter` **branch** is now pushed to the master project

at  `https://github.com/yardpenalty/mainproject.git`

Let's say the package project is located at

```
https://github.com/yardpenalty/mypackage.git
```

Keep in mind the mainproject uses this package in production so we can't make changes by simply pushing them to this package (among other reasons). Let's say a web dev has to edit this package to make changes on production.

A simple branch wont work either because we can't see our changes without publishing the package etc.

**Fork Usage:**
Now is when we have to do a little bit of trickery with our package so we create a clone of the production package via a fork. The composer.json files can be updated to point to the fork which is now located at a **User or Group path**

So we will create a fork in `https://github.com/yardpenalty/mypackage.git`

and call it `https://github.com/yardpenalty/yards/mypackage.git`

Now we can update our **composer.json** file to point to this package in our "repositories":[ array like such such and away we go!

```
 {
            "type": "github",
            "url": "https://github.com/yardpenalty/yard/mypackage.git"
 }
```

]