# how to understand fork and branch on github

Tags: github

both fork and branch can make a copy of original project.
we can use pull request to merge the copy made by fork or branch with original project.

so what's the different between them. They seem to solve the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between fork and branch on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009600/difference-between-fork-and-branch-on-github)

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen   no ,my problem is different