# Difference between two git rebasing methods

Tags: git, git-rebase

I would like to perform updates from master into my local branch which has been branched out of master earlier on the time axis (from M2 change).
Master is denoted with `M` changes, my local branch with `L` changes

New branch was created from master's `M2`:

```
 M1->M2-->M3->M4
      \
       L1->L2
```

I guess my outcome should be for my local branch as follows:

```
M1->M2->M3->M4->L1->L2
```

Which means recreating my local branch to have first all master changes and only then my local branch changes on top of it, like mentioned in:
   https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing
(correct me if I'm wrong)

My question is whether one of the following methods is not creating the above desired flow, and if so why?

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase 
git checkout branch_to_update
git rebase master` (method mentioned in attlasian tautorial)
```

VS

```
git checkout branch_to_update
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in both other answers, the effect is generally pretty much the same.  [msanford has pointed out one definite and one potential difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50026835/1256452) but there are more.  To see what and why, we should disassemble `git pull` into its constituents.

#### All the finicky details (warning: long)

With a few minor exceptions (such as running it in a completely empty repository), `git pull` means:

1. run `git fetch` with various options and arguments; then
2. run a second Git command, chosen before step 1 runs, also with various options and arguments.

The second command is usually `git merge` but you can tell Git to use `git rebase`.  The options and arguments passed to the two commands depend on options passed to `git pull` and other configuration settings, plus the result or results of the fetch in step 1.

As a sort of general rule, though, arguments passed to `git pull` are passed to `git fetch`, so this means that your second command sequence—which passes `origin master` to `git pull`—passes `origin master` to `git fetch` as well.  If you run `git pull` *without* these arguments, as in your first command sequence, Git extracts the *remote* (usually `origin`) and the *upstream branch name* (usually the same as the current branch name) from your configuration, specifically from the results of these two commands:<sup>1</sup>

```
git config --get branch.$branch.remote
git config --get branch.$branch.merge
```

(where `$branch` is the current branch).  If the current branch is `master`, this uses `branch.master.remote` as the remote.  That's what we mean in terms of assuming there is only one remote.  The `merge` name is probably `master`, but if not, that's another assumption we have to make, before we can claim that these do the same thing.

---

<sup>1</sup>if your Git is old enough, `git pull` is a shell script, and it literally runs various other Git commands.  If it's newer, `git pull` has been converted to a C-language program and it has these built directly in.

---

#### Rebase copies commits, then switches to the new copies

What `git rebase` does gets complicated if we delve into all the details, but at a high level, its job is to *copy* commits.  To see which commits it will copy, you should draw the commit graph, or use `git log --graph` to have Git draw it for you.  (Some GUIs always draw it, and some web interfaces <sub><sup>**cough*GitHub*cough**</sup></sub> never let you view it!)  With a graph drawing, it's easy—well, sometimes easy—to tell which commits get copied:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E--F--G   <-- br
```

Rebasing your branch `br` on your master copies three commits, here `E` through `G`, placing the copies after commit `D`.  This is similar to what you drew.

Suppose we add `origin/` remote-tracking names, and show that your own `master` is currently pointing to commit `B` while `origin/master` is currently pointing to commit `D`, like this:

```
          C--D   <-- origin/master
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          E--F--G   <-- br
```

Now we can see that we must rebase `br` onto `origin/master` in order to have the copies go after commit `D`.  Rebasing onto `master` will put the copies after `B`, which is where the originals are, so there's no need to copy after all.  (Whether rebase actually copies, or just re-uses the originals, is one of the finicky details: it depends on the `-f` option, for instance.)

Once the copying is done, `git rebase` simply re-points the branch name to point to the final copied (or re-used) commit, which we can call `G'` here to note that it's a copy of `G`.  The original commits are effectively abandoned, although reflog entries for HEAD and for the original branch, and the name `ORIG_HEAD`, temporarily retain them:

```
               E'-F'-G'  <-- br
              /
          C--D   <-- origin/master
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          E--F--G   [abandoned, but see ORIG_HEAD and reflogs]
```

The reflog entries keep the originals available for at least 30 more days by default.  Eventually `ORIG_HEAD` moves elsewhere due to other operations, and the reflog entries expire, and the original commits get garbage-collected.

#### Now we can look at your original command sequences

Let's suppose, for argument sake, that we have the graph above (like yours but with one more commit on branch `br`, and we already ran `git fetch` to get `origin/master` updated).  Then the Atlassian command sequence begins with these two commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
```

This will attach our `HEAD` to our `master`, checking out commit `B`; then, assuming the upstream is `origin/master`, run `git fetch origin master` to update our `origin/master`, which in this case leaves `origin/master` pointing to `D`.  If we had not run `git fetch` yet this would *obtain* commits `C` and `D` and point our `origin/master` to `D`.

Last, this will run `git rebase <hash-of-commit-D>`.  The rebase operation uses the hash ID because it uses the traces that `git fetch` leaves in `.git/FETCH_HEAD` and, depending on exact Git version and more details we'll ignore here, also uses `git merge-base --fork-point` to find a commit hash so as to recover from upstream rebases.  (This process sometimes goes wrong, depending on your own work-flow, and I am not sure I like the default behavior.)

Once this is all done we get to the last two commands:

```
git checkout br
git rebase master
```

The first attaches `HEAD` to the name `br`, checking out commit `G`.  The rebase then copies the `E-F-G` commit sequence to come after the commit to which `master` now points.  So, ignoring all the reflog entries, we get the graph:

```
                E'-F'-G'  <-- br (HEAD)
               /
...--A--B--C--D   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          E--F--G   [abandoned]
```

Compare this with your shorter sequence of commands:

```
git checkout br
git pull --rebase origin master
```

The checkout attaches `HEAD` to `br`.  The `pull` runs `git fetch origin master`, which makes sure we have commits `C-D` (if we did not already fetch them) and updates `origin/master` (if our Git is at least 1.8.4), then runs `git rebase <hash-of-D>` which copies the `E-F-G` chain, giving:

```
               E'-F'-G'  <-- br
              /
          C--D   <-- origin/master
         /
...--A--B   <-- master
         \
          E--F--G   [abandoned]
```

So the key difference is that your own name, `master`, never gets updated to point to commit `D`.

#### What I recommend instead

It's important to note (and know) that if you run `git fetch` *yourself*—this is my preferred method—this will tell your Git to call up the other Git at the remote's URL, and have the other Git list for your Git, *all* of its (origin's, we assume) branches.  Your Git will then obtain *all* the commits they have that you don't and put them into your Git's repository, and update *all* of your remote-tracking names like `origin/master` and `origin/develop` and so on.

In other words, your remote-tracking names, which are your Git's way of remembering *their* branches, will *all* get updated.  This is usually a good thing.  It's only bad if they have a lot of branches and a lot of big commits and your network connection is slow; in that case, you might have to wait a long time to download everything.

When `git pull` runs `git fetch`, though, it runs it with a limiting option.  For instance, if your `git pull` runs:

```
git fetch origin master
```

that tells your Git to call up the Git at the URL for `origin` and ask them to transfer *only* commits new to *their `master`*.  If they have updates to their `develop` and `production` and `feature/tall` and so on, you don't get any of those—you only get new commits that are on their `master`.  Your Git updates your `origin/master` to remember the new commits,<sup>2</sup> but leaves the rest of your remote-tracking names unchanged.

In your second command sequence, you run an explicit `git pull origin master` (with `--rebase` as well), so this limits your Git to updating your `origin/master`.  In your *first* command sequence, you run `git pull` with no arguments—but `git pull` inserts `origin` and `master`, assuming those are the configured settings for your `master` branch, so this also limits your Git to updating only your `origin/master`.

I mention all this because I recommend not using `git pull` at all.  Run `git fetch` yourself—you can let it default to fetching everything from `origin`—and then run whichever `git rebase` commands you want!  After the `fetch` you have all the commits and all the appropriate `origin/*` names; you can then run:

```
git checkout <whatever-name>
git rebase origin/<whatever-other-name>
```

to copy whatever commits and/or adjust whichever of your own branch names you want to update.  The one fetch lets you do any number of merge, reset, fast-forward pseudo-merge, or rebase operations.  You can also *look at* what got fetched, before you decide what other Git commands to run!

---

<sup>2</sup>This assumes your Git is at least version 1.8.4.  If not, this kind of `git fetch` fails to update even `origin/master`.  You must run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` to get your remote-tracking names updated!

Comment: `tag:canonical-answer` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming [there is only one remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009600/difference-between-fork-and-branch-on-github), those two will have the same effect.

In the first case, you are updating a local copy of `master`, and then rebasing.

In the second case, you're rebasing *directly from a remote* repository.

Use the second option when you might not want to bother to update your local copy of the branch you're rebasing from.

For example, we have a main `develop` branch off which we make topic branches, e.g., `feature/0001`. While working, I keep `feature/0001` checked out and simply `git pull -r origin develop` from time to time. In this case, having a local up-to-date copy of `develop` is irrelevant.

*After* my feature branch is merged, I checkout and pull `develop`, and then create a new `feature/0002` branch from that updated copy.

---

Additionally, note that it will actually create *this* as a result:

```
M1 -> M2 -> M3 -> M4 -> L1' -> L2'
```

What do I mean by `L1'`? Roughly, it will create a new commit -- with a new SHA identifier -- with the same content. So it's not the same commit *per se*.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> git checkout branch_to_update
> git rebase master
> ```

or

> ```
> git checkout branch_to_update
> git pull --rebase origin master
> ```

these are same result but different ways
`pull --rebase` parameter briefly using rebase