# getting stats from a different branch

Tags: git, gitosis

I'm using [gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git) and [gitstats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/) to host some pvt code. Everything is working well, if you dont want to run stats on a branch other than master.

So, question is how do I:

1. set a branch for gitstats to use (does not seem possible)

   or
2. set the 'default' branch of this repo to something other than master

Going with option 2 gitstats can just carry on working as it has, and the code will just be the more upto date dev branch.

Thanks

P.S. yes, gitosis is old. :)

### Answer

```
cd /path/to/repo
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<default-branch-you-want>
```

also `git symbolic-ref HEAD` will output the current 'default'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have access to thebare repos managed by your (old ;)) gitosis, you can change the the symbolic-ref for `HEAD` in said bare repo (see "[How do I change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides “master”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master/2962737)".

Then you can check if gitstats fetch the information from the right branch.

Comment: yes, thanks that is the one. ill update the question with the exact command :)