# why does bare repository have HEAD

Tags: git

I'm wondering what's the purpose of `HEAD` in bare repository? Is it just used when repository is cloned to know which branch to checkout in cloned repository?

Please note, this question is not about `what is HEAD`, but given its functions I'm wondering why it's needed inside `bare` repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is HEAD in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git)

Comment: I guess that this is becuase, you can push commit (not branch) to remote, and then you need some starting point of DAG

Comment: @LukaRahne, yeah, but `HEAD` doesn't point to commits, it points to branch refs, so even if I push commits the starting point can be found using branch refs.

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but I guess that if i checkout commit (localy) head will point to commit, not branch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can you please name a case where HEAD is used in a bare repository?

See "[`t/t1430-bad-ref-name.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2dfb2e07cb0cb979f630643b57dca579a0359a9d/t/t7103-reset-bare.sh#L48-L67)"

You can do a soft reset in a bare repo, which means you can move HEAD (current commit) around, which is one way to [change the default branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764517/6309).

That means that when you clone a bare repo, the default branch checked out in the non-bare clone will be the one referenced by the bare repo HEAD.

Comment: thanks, so basically my this assumption is correct _Is it just used when repository is cloned to know which branch to checkout in cloned repository?_ ? I'm also wondering why you specified _HEAD (current commit)_, while HEAD usually points to a branch ref even in a bare repository. And what does soft-resetting of `HEAD` do? Move the branch ref that `HEAD` points to?

Comment: @Maximus because HEAD doesn't always reference a branch. It can also just reference a commit, in which case this is a "detached HEAD": http://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309

Comment: Note to self: this is my 1000th Enlightened badge (https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=6309)

Comment: When we clone from the bare repo, we see an `origin/HEAD`, but why isn't it seen when we clone from a repo hosted on Github?

Comment: @huggie Because [GitHub defines a default branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838756/6309) (which a bare repo does not have by default, as [mentioned here](https://superuser.com/a/1192881/141))