# Push several branches under a "folder"

Tags: git

I have several branches with the following scheme

```
manual_test/other_test
manual_test/one_more
```

I would like to kjnow if there is anyway to push all the branches under manual_test to a remote

Comment: Using '/' will display the branches in groups. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025768/9141014.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The full spelling of what push and fetch work with is called a "[refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)", it specifies what refs to pick from the source and how they're supposed to look at the destination.  When you say `git push origin master`, Git looks at `master` and fills in the bits you left out, `master` is much easier to type than `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`.

What you want is `git push origin refs/heads/manual_test/*:refs/heads/manual_test/*`