# git change default branch (gitolite)

Tags: git, rename, git-branch, gitolite

I've got a repository with branches: master and devel. Master is the default one. I want to rename master into prod and make it default (and push it to the server). How to do this?

Repository is hosted in gitolite (if it matters).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have access to the server in order to change the symbolic-ref of HEAD to the branch you have pushed there (`prod`).

```
git-symbolic-ref HEAD refs/head/prod
```

I tentatively proposed a way to do that from a client at the end of "[How do I change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides “master”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485590/6309)", but it is easier if you can log on the server directly.

Note: **with the latest Gitolite V3, you actually can run that command** (see "[non-core commands](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/non-core.html)"):

```
/home/git/gitolite# gitolite symbolic-ref -h

Usage:    ssh git@host symbolic-ref <repo> <arguments to git-symbolic-ref>

allow 'git symbolic-ref' over a gitolite connection
```

So, through an ssh command, you actually can change HEAD for remote repos managed by gitolite (V3).

```
ssh git@host symbolic-ref <repo> refs/head/prod
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if the repository is hosted on gitolite?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz absolutely. I just edited my answer to address that setup.

Answer (score 3):

I had to use (Gitolite 3.5.3):

```
ssh git@host symbolic-ref <repo> HEAD refs/heads/prod
```