# Using Gitlab's API, how can I switch between branches?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to switch from my `master` branch to my `development` branch using Gitlab's API, I've researched all the documented API's available [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/README.md), but there isn't such an API.

Has someone tried this before as this is a very common scenario?

Is it possible to do the same via the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch between branches?

On the GitLab server side (which is what the Gitlab API refers to), you don't switch branches, since GitLab is managing [*bare* repos](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html) (repos without a working tree, with any branch checked out).

You might mean: "How to change the default branch" (the one checked out by default when a user clone a remote repo managed by GitLab).

That is possible with gitolite (see "[git change default branch (gitolite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949093/git-change-default-branch-gitolite)").
However, it isn't with GitLab: the relevant API would be "[Projects](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/projects.md)", but the "[branch](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/projects.md#branches)" section doesn't include anything to change the symbolic ref of `HEAD` of a bare repo managed by GitLab.

That means you have to go on the server itself, within the bare repo, in order to execute a:

```
git-symbolic-ref HEAD refs/head/development
```

---

[onionjake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049112/onionjake) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341328/using-gitlabs-api-how-can-i-switch-between-branches/17341741#comment38679073_17341741):

> If you are using the omnibus packages you might not have git installed in the usual spot.
>   I had to do:

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/development.
```

Comment: I wanted to switch branches(or more appropriately change my default branch)because I wanted to get repository tree for different branches(for master, development etc), if you see Gitlab's web interface, when you click on files tab, you can select the branch in a dropdown list, the repository tree changes. How do they do it? 
Is there some way I could do it using the existing API? I am open to write a new API for that but it would be better if I could just use an existing one.

Comment: I got it thank you very much once again, I just had to send a ref_name parameter as branch name to list repository tree API.

Comment: @ArifNadeem yes, listing the repo tree is supported.

Comment: If you are using the omnibus packages you might not have git installed in the usual spot.  I had to do `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/development`.

Comment: @onionjake good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.