# New repo added to gitolite on server, getting "unable to checkout" when try to push there

Tags: git, gitolite

I've got a server set up with a handful of git repositories using [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html).

I added a new repository by updating `gitolite.conf` to have an entry for the new repo, and pushing (as described [here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#repos)).

I then added a git remote entry on my local machine so that I can push to the new gitolite repo.

When I try and push any branch other than master there, I see the following error:

```
remote: warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout
```

Comment: Actually, I realise now that the failed clone was happening in a git hook which was attempting to clone *from* the gitolite repo (as part of copying the code from the repo into a publicly-visible folder).  So I'm not sure whether gitolite itself actually hits this problem.  But I'll leave this Q&A up as the `git symbolic-ref` command (see my answer) is indeed the one to use for `nonexistent ref` errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that gitolite repos default to using master as their default branch, and so it was looking in the master branch for the refs that I was pushing, and they weren't there.

I found the way to fix that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949093/git-change-default-branch-gitolite) - using the `git symbolic-ref` command.  As that post explains, the command can be run via gitolite itself in newer versions, or you can log into the remote server and do it there.

In my case, I went to my new repo on the server (i.e. `/home/git/repositories/my_new_one.git`) and ran `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/develop`, switching the default branch to `develop`.

I could now push the develop branch there as I needed.

Comment: I approve of that method ;) +1