# Not on a branch after clone

Tags: git, git-clone

I cloned a repository, that has only one remote branch, namely master. After the cloning I get the message, that I'm in a detached HEAD state and git branch also says (no branch).

Git log shows only the initial commit of the repository. After I enter git checkout master, everything is as it should be.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Were you already in a git project when you cloned?

Comment: If you have access to the original repository, make sure that the HEAD reference points to the `master` branch.

Comment: Yes. I made all commits except the initial one. I also worked with git before and did nothing new that could trigger such a behaviour.

Comment: I am the only one working on this repo. But I don't have access to the server. How do I make HEAD point to master?

Comment: Without access to the server, you can't fix the problem, you can only work around it by doing an explicit "git checkout" after the initial clone.

Comment: @user1839433 You can make HEAD point to master by doing `git checkout master`

Answer (score 1):

That would be because HEAD on the remote repository doesn't reference a branch, but a commit.

```
git-symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
```

That would change `HEAD` on remote (as [I mentioned 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485590/6309)), but supposes you have access to the remote repo (which you don't have).

So [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill)'s suggestion is still the best:

```
git clone -b master /url/of/remote/repo
```