# Set default branch using REST API

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it somehow possible to set the default branch of a Git repository using Visual Studio Team Service REST API? There is an [API for repositories](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/repositories) and an UI for setting the default branch, but I couldn't find a possibility to set the default branch through the REST API.

Comment: Related (not duplicate) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API can be found here: [Update repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/update)

Call:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}?api-version=5.1
```

With payload:

```
{
    "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/{branchName}"
}
```

Comment: Note that `repositoryId` is a guid which you can get by calling `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryName}?api-version=5.1`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to do this with REST API for now.

Answer (score 1):

The API now has a way to change the default branch. [The documentation is here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories), under the "Modify a Repository" section.

Comment: Can you add a small piece of code to make it a better answer?

Comment: Answers shouldn't only consist of links. If you add the sample available in the link to the answer I can accept this as the answer.