# GitHub remote symbolic ref/branch alias

Tags: git, github

On a GitHub repo, I'd like the `master` branch to actually be an alias to a `x.y.z` branch. As a consequence, all fetch/push from x.y.z and master would result to the exact same result. I do want to keep the `master` branch because people are used to it, but also want the `x.y.z` branch to not make master a special-case of a branch name (other branches are `a.b.c`, `d.e.f`...).

Is there a way to achieve that on GitHub? Or on a Git remote repository in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On GitHub side, you can change [the default branch](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/).
On a remote repo side, you can [similarly change the default branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485590/6309).

Setting a branch *alias* is not directly possible on GitHub side.
It is on a remote hosting git repo server you have access to:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/master refs/heads/x.y.z
```

But the alias part would not propagate to a git cloned repo: while every new clone would checkout by default `x.y.z`, their user would have to setup the alias locally.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what if I 'git clone --bare' the GitHub repo, run the 'git symbolic-ref' command you advised ans the use 'git pushh --mirror'?

Comment: @Mickael you can try, but I believe the alias will not be pushed, only the resolved commit pointed by said alias. And the default branch reference will *not* be pushed either: that reference remains local to the repo, to be used when other are cloning it.

Comment: Ok, I tried and indeed, the symbolic-ref branch isn't interpreted as a symbolic-refs branch after a 'git push --mirror'. It's created as a regular branch. The limitation is both on the Git protocol that seems to ignore symbolic-refs and push symbolic branch as regular one, and on GitHub that doesn't provide support for "aliases".

Comment: @Mickael I agree. Those symbolic-ref and aliases are for local use only.