# Create an empty Git repository with branch name as prod

Tags: git, branch, git-init

I would like to create a new git repository using `git init` command with branch name as **prod**. I searched all options supported by `git init` command in this [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) to override the default branch name **master**.

Unfortunately, there's no such option.

Customizing the source code of [git](https://github.com/git/git) is the only option?

Comment: What situation are you in that an empty repo looks like a good thing to have available for people to clone?

Answer (score 4):

With [git 2.28.0](https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/#introducing-init-defaultbranch), the default branch name can be configured with the setting `init.defaultBranch`

> git config --global init.defaultBranch prod

More Info: https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/#introducing-init-defaultbranch

Answer (score 2):

If it is a new git repository, you can just do

```
git checkout -b prod
```

And you will stand on a new branch named "prod".

Or, just rename the master branch if you already have committed some thing to it:

```
git branch -m master prod
```

This code can make a new repository with a branch named "prod"

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init && git checkout -b prod
```

Comment: Getting this error, **error: refname refs/heads/master not found
fatal: Branch rename failed**

Comment: If there is nothing in the master branch(You have not committed any thing to it), you cannot rename it because the branch doesn't exist.

Comment: You can commit some thing and then rename it, or just checkout a new branch.

Comment: Ok. I get your point. But I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve any commits. Just like how `git init` initializes an empty repository with branch **master**, I need a similar command for initializing an empty repository with branch **prod**. Am sorry, if my question was not clear.

Comment: Just try
`git init && git checkout -b prod`
I think this is what you want.
This command will create a new repo and checkout a new branch "prod". Because master branch has nothing, it will disappear.

Comment: Cloned worktree from this empty repo shows branch as master.

Comment: Yes, because your repo is empty, clone it is just like `git init`. Is your question how to clone empty repo and customizing the name of master branch? Which branch you first commit to will become the "master branch" of the repo.

Comment: Just to clarify, my question is about creating an empty repository with branch name as `prod`. Users cloning this new empty repository should see branch as `prod`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the default branch that users have checked out when they clone, you have to [create a `HEAD` pointer on the remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1485578/4233593). The reference would look something like this in your local repository by running:

```
git branch -avv
```

> ```
> remotes/origin/HEAD       -> origin/master
> ```

By default, this is `master`, but you can [change the default branch in Github](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/). Other hosting services have similar methods [discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1485578/4233593). If you are self-hosted or have shell/file-system access to the remote server, then you can manually set this with:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/prod
```

After fetching the remote, you should see this updated:

> ```
> remotes/origin/HEAD       -> origin/prod
> ```

Now when users clone your repository, then they will automatically have the `prod` branch checked out.

---

However, your specific question in regards to `init` has led me to discover an interesting oddity with Github - even if the repository only has one branch named `prod` it doesn't automatically create the `HEAD` pointer.

Let's create a bare repository, set the branch name, and then commit:

```
git init
git checkout -b prod
touch file1
git add .
git commit -m 'init repo'
```

Create the remote repository:

```
curl --data '{"name":"myproject"}' -u YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Add the remote and push:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/myproject.git
git push -u origin prod
```

To test this out, let's hop into a new folder and clone the project to see what it will look like for others.

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/myproject.git
```

> ```
> Cloning into 'myproject'...
> remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
> remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
> Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
> Checking connectivity... done.
> warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
> ```

Especially note that last line:

> ```
> warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
> ```

For some reason Github didn't create that `HEAD` pointer for us, so git by default is going to fallback to using the `master` branch, which doesn't exist in our repo. So when you `cd` into the new folder you'll notice that you actually have checked out a bare branch called `master` with no commits, yet the `prod` branch is there if you just check it out. This is very annoying, so it seems like we will still have to manually update the default branch on Github.

This is where it gets weird. Github already shows that branch as the default, so *we can't update it*.

[image]

The only way I figured out how to get around this was to create another temporary branch, change it to the default branch, and then change it right back.

Now when anyone clones it, then they will have the `prod` branch automatically checked out.