# Git Clone: Could not resolve branch/origin

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git and am trying to clone a repository on my local using Github Desktop.

However I get an error when I try to do this. If I check the log it ends with the error:

> GetBranch`1|Could not resolve branch origin/drupal-dev-env

Googling this reveals nothing useful (to me, with my level of understanding).

Would anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Might be the branch is private, or inaccessible. Make sure you (and GitHub) have the permissions to the location you're cloning to.

Comment: Did you just run a git clone or was it something else, please mention the command that you ran

Comment: @aliasav I used the GUI to try and clone. Not sure what actual commands the GUI sent

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the [default branch of the remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485590/6309) is one which does not exist in the remote repo.

Try to clone that repo in command line, and see if you can list the branches actually fetched (even if the clone fail to checkout any branch) with:

```
git branch -avv
```